# C++ linux : error: ‘move’ is not a member of ‘std’ how to get around it?

Tags: c++, boost, std, move, move-semantics

So on my VS2010 I can compile code like :

```
boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> internal_thread;
boost::packaged_task<void> internal_task_w(boost::bind(&thread_pool::internal_run, this, internal_thread));
internal_thread = boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread>( new boost::thread(std::move(internal_task_w)));
```

first 2 lines are ok with boost 1.47.0 and linux... but on std::move it gives `error: ‘move’ is not a member of ‘std’`. On VS2010 it does not require any special header. So I wonder which header it requires on linux and is it in its STD anyway? If not how to get around it with boost or something?

Comment: Related: [What std::move() is?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413470/what-stdmove-is)

Comment: To answer the "which header" bit, it's in `<utility>`, but you may well find that many other standard headers include that in any given implementation, hence the impression that it doesn't require any special header.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To get g++ into C++11 (or C++0x) mode, you have to add the command-line parameter `-std=c++0x` on versions <= 4.6, nowadays you can also use `-std=c++11`.

Comment: On gcc 4.7.3 I also had to `#include <utility>` to get rid of this error.

Comment: Thanks, -std=c++11 is the solution. Surprised, c++11 is not the default compiler for Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Comment: How do you make it work using cmake and make? How would you pass this option?

Comment: @PlasmaBinturong Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851247/how-to-activate-c-11-in-cmake#31010221

Answer (score 1):

You are using the most recent Visual Studio, but not the most recent GCC.  The std::move capability is available in the most recent GCC.  It is a new feature of C++11.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use `std::move` because your compiler does not support c++11.