# How do I activate C++ 11 in CMake?

Tags: c++11, cmake

When I try to run a CMake generated makefile to compile my program, I get the error that

> range based for loops are not supported in C++ 98 mode.

I tried adding `add_definitions(-std=c++0x)` to my `CMakeLists.txt`, but it did not help.

I tried this too:

```
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
    add_definitions(-std=gnu++0x)
endif()
```

When I do `g++ --version`, I get:

> g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1

I have also tried `SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++0x")`, which also does not work.

I do not understand how I can activate C++ 11 features using CMake.

Comment: The `SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++0x")` works fine for me, so there is probably a problem somewhere else in the CMakeLists file. Make sure you don't accidentally overwrite the contents of CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS later on.

Comment: add_definitions(-std=c++11) works for me with CMake 2.8.8

Comment: @ComicSansMS: You are totally right! I overwrote it, which was my own mistake. I have corrected it, and now it is working fine! C++11 stuff is very cool! I wanted to loop on a vector of structures, which would require iterator and needless coding noise if I did not have range based for loops. I guess I could use BOOST_FOREACH though, but oh well...

Comment: For CMake ≥3.1, [__`set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)`__](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/variable/CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD.html) (before defining the target) is the best way.

Comment: @tuple_cat You can do it target-based as well. But be aware that `CXX_STANDARD` does **not** work on MSVC, so basically you have to fall back to `target_compile_features` if you want something that works cross-platform.

Comment: Questions about CMake get stale _very_ fast here on SO. In 2020, you should absolutely not be fiddling with compiler flags in your CMakeLists.txt to do this. See [MateuszL's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52382437/2137996) if you just want to build with C++11, 14, etc. See [eyelash's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49597621/2137996) if you additionally want propagating behavior (ie. users of your library must compile with that C++ version)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As it turns out, `SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++0x")` does activate many C++11 features. The reason it did not work was that the statement looked like this:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++0x ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g -ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs")
```

Following this approach, somehow the `-std=c++0x` flag was overwritten and it did not work. Setting the flags one by one or using a list method is working.

```
list( APPEND CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++0x ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g -ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs")
```

Comment: I always just use: SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11") # for gcc >= 4.7, or c++0x for 4.6

Comment: I once did a little script for that (not complete though): https://github.com/Morwenn/POLDER/blob/master/cmake/set_cxx_norm.cmake

Comment: -1. If you specify any CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS from the command line, the second method will produce a semicolon in the build command (and repeat the original CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS twice).

Comment: instead of manually adding the -g flag you should set the CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE variable to debug: http://voices.canonical.com/jussi.pakkanen/2013/03/26/a-list-of-common-cmake-antipatterns/

Comment: The `CXX_STANDARD` property is better as it is compiler-agnostic.

Answer (score 487):

CMake 3.1 was released in 2014 and introduced the [`CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD.html) variable that you can use.  If you know that you will always have CMake 3.1 or later available, you can just write this in your top-level CMakeLists.txt file, or put it right before any new target is defined:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

If you need to support ancient versions of CMake (quite unlikely these days), here is a macro I came up with that you can use:

```
macro(use_cxx11)
  if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS "3.1")
    if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "GNU")
      set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")
    endif ()
  else ()
    set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
  endif ()
endmacro(use_cxx11)
```

The macro only supports GCC right now, but it should be straight-forward to expand it to other compilers.

Then you could write `use_cxx11()` at the top of any CMakeLists.txt file that defines a target that uses C++11.

### CMake issue #15943 for clang users targeting macOS

If you are using CMake and clang to target macOS there is a [bug](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/15943) that can cause the `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` feature to simply not work (not add any compiler flags).  Make sure that you do one of the following things:

- Use [`cmake_minimum_required`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_minimum_required.html) to require CMake 3.0 or later, or
- Set policy CMP0025 to NEW with the following code at the top of your CMakeLists.txt file before the `project` command:

  ```
    # Fix behavior of CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD when targeting macOS.
    if (POLICY CMP0025)
      cmake_policy(SET CMP0025 NEW)
    endif ()
  ```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It does not require touching each target's properties individually, and works cross-platform.

Comment: Agreed, this should be the accepted answer as of CMake 3.1+.  It doesn't seem to work for me on the mac though.  You can force it to give you --std=c++11 with --stdlib=libc++, the default on the Mac.  Instead CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD always includes the gnu extensions if they are supported, and the result doesn't seem to build against --stdlib=libc++.  Instead you have to switch to gnu's --stdlib=libstdc++.

The Mac is the special case though.  For Linux, choosing gnu++11 with libstdc++ is the norm.  Of course, that is easily corrected with a if(APPLE) add_compile_options() to tack on the flags.

Comment: This works for me for CMake 3.5 on macOS. Big props to David for putting together the macro as well.

Comment: This should not be used, the good way to do it now is to specify properties per target, and not per directory. Especially if you're writing a library: use the accepted answer !

Comment: I think that for most people it is more convenient to specify the language you are using in just one place.  But this is starting to get very opinion-based.

Comment: One problem of this approach is that `gnu++11` is enforced, even when these variables are defined `set(CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION clang)`
`set(CMAKE_ANDROID_STL_TYPE c++_static)`. For me the only viable way was the classic `set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")`

Comment: GroovyCakes, hey good catch.  Recent versions of GCC don't care if you use two dashes but some old versions were picky, so I changed it.

Comment: Does not work for me on macOS (CMake 3.9.4, homebrew-clang). Saving others the despair. Not sure why it works for @EvanMoran but not me.

Comment: @Unapiedra: It's a CMake bug but you can work around it, see https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/15943

Comment: As @Antonio hinted, always append flags, never set directly as that might overwrite any other set upstream (or passed from command line).
Correct: `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")`.

Comment: The CMake version check makes things worse. I have CMake 3.3 with intel c compiler and `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` does not work.  Simply `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")` works.

Answer (score 194):

The CMake command [**`target_compile_features()`**](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_features.html) is used to specify the required C++ feature **`cxx_range_for`**. CMake will then induce the C++ standard to be used.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0 FATAL_ERROR)
project(foobar CXX)
add_executable(foobar main.cc)
target_compile_features(foobar PRIVATE cxx_range_for)
```

There is no need to use **`add_definitions(-std=c++11)`** or to modify the CMake variable **`CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`**, because CMake will make sure the C++ compiler is invoked with the appropriate command line flags.

Maybe your C++ program uses other C++ features than `cxx_range_for`. The CMake global property [**`CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES`**](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES.html) lists the C++ features you can choose from.

Instead of using `target_compile_features()` you can also specify the C++ standard explicitly by setting the CMake properties
[**`CXX_STANDARD`**](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html)
and
[**`CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED`**](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED.html) for your CMake target.

See also [my more detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20165220/757777).

Comment: It seems the edit from today is misleading. CMake 3.0.0 does not contain target_compile_features. Correct me if I'm wrong. I think the command is only present in the nightly builds of CMake.

Comment: Urgh, it appears you are correct. My bad. I looked it up but must have landed [here](http://www.steveire.com/cmake-future/command/target_compile_features.html) thinking I was on the main CMake documentation page. I've submitted an edit to revert my changes. Sorry for the noise!

Comment: I'd say this is the most accurate answer

Comment: I think this is how it is supposed to do. The other answers just manually add flags and therefore introduce incompatibilities. However this seems to be only available in CMake 3.1+

Comment: @UliKöhler this is actually still not available, and *may possibly* turn up for *some compilers* in 3.2. Don't use this method in the short term; its completely not portable.

Comment: Any idea how to do this in CMake 2.6?

Comment: What to do when a feature is not listed such as `std::future`?

Comment: See my comment to the answer, be aware `CXX_STANDARD` does not work on MSVC.

Comment: There are `cxx_std_XX` features now which make it possible to set standard easily. That's great!

Answer (score 92):

I am using

```
include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++11" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++0x" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
if(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
elseif(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x")
else()
        message(STATUS "The compiler ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} has no C++11 support. Please use a different C++ compiler.")
endif()
```

But if you want to play with `C++11`, `g++ 4.6.1` is pretty old.
Try to get a newer `g++` version.

Comment: This is, for me, the only right and nice answer to this question, with current (rolled out) cmake on most recent Linux' using g++.

Comment: Copied and pasted this and it worked perfectly. I am on Cygwin using CMAKE 2.8.9. I know about most of the approaches I'm reading here because I follow the CMAKE mailing list and I've ported WebKit to a variety of compilers. The thing we had done for WebKit ports was to install CMake 2.8.12. However because I know Cygwin's CMAKE is old, I wanted something that applied to that version. (Not porting WebKit to Cygwin, sorry)

Comment: Great, this is a drop-in for old CMake and g++ 4.6 (and future-proof). I also upvoted the `CXX_STANDARD`-based answers, but this was the only answer useful in my situation.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, however it's not clear what is the minimum cmake version needed to use that module. cmake --help-module doesn't help much about it.

Comment: @JanSegre the module first appeared in 2.4, http://www.cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=commitdiff;h=72b38e3aa7ba5fa4a70144e05de36bc99fda173a

Comment: Thank, it works very good. Just a note for anyone using GCC 4.6, most code that I tried and depends on C++11 throws errors with it.

Answer (score 67):

The easiest way to set the Cxx standard is:

```
 set_property(TARGET tgt PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

See [the CMake documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html) for more details.

Comment: Yes, this definitely looks like one of the best ways to do it in modern CMake (3.1+)

Comment: Or you can just `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)` to define the default property for all targets created after that.

Comment: This is also the solution you need if you want to set different C++ standards on different targets, because the `set` command suggested by @emlai is global and affects all subsequent targets.

Answer (score 46):

On modern CMake (>= 3.1) the best way to set global requirements is:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
```

It translates to "I want C++11 for all targets, it's not optional, I don’t want to use any GNU or Microsoft  extensions."
As of C++17, this still is IMHO the best way.

Source: *[Enabling C++11 And Later In CMake](https://crascit.com/2015/03/28/enabling-cxx11-in-cmake/)*

Comment: This way is not ideal for newest versions of C++ if you don't have the latest CMake. E.g. you can't enable C++2a this way until CMake 3.12.

Comment: No reason not to have the latest CMake, though. Chocolatey, Homebrew, and Snap all have up-to-date packages.

Comment: Note that these have to be set before defining any targets; failing to do this leads to only targets defined after setting them to get affected. This is understandable since they're the defaults.

Comment: Not any more in "more modern cmake = 3.12"... prefer `target_compile_options(project_name PRIVATE option1 ...)` or `target_compile_definitions` or still `target_compile_features(ao-project_name PRIVATE some_feature)` if you target between C++11 and C++17 but not above.

Comment: @Sandburg why would I prefer to specify multiple features for multiple targets separately? Do you think this is common to have various expectations for various targets in single project? I knew about this feature but honestly can't think of single use-case when this is desirable as primary approach.
In any case: according to linked article it worked in 3.1

Answer (score 45):

For CMake 3.8 and newer you can use

```
target_compile_features(target PUBLIC cxx_std_11)
```

If you want the generation step to fail if the toolchain cannot adhere to this standard, you can make this required.

```
set_target_properties(target PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
```

If you want strict adherence to standard C++ i.e. avoid C++ extensions offered by your compiler (like GCC's `-std=gnu++17`), additionally set

```
set_target_properties(target PROPERTIES CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
```

This is documented in detail at [An Introduction to Modern CMake](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/chapters/features/cpp11.html) -> Adding Features -> C++11 and Beyond.  It also offers advice on how to achieve this on older versions of CMake if you're constrained to those.

Comment: this is the way recommended of latest version of CMake

Comment: What is the function of `PUBLIC` here?

Comment: @RotsiserMho `PUBLIC` means that other targets that depend on your target will use C++11 as well. For example if your target is a library then all targets that link against your library with `target_link_libraries` will be compiled with C++11 support.

Comment: As of now, this is technically the best way to define the standard version and should be the accepted answer (although Erik's still stands, should one need fine grained settings).

Comment: Is there a way to set global/CMAKE_ default target features? Or does it mean we have to repeat setting language standard for every target?

Answer (score 18):

The easiest way:

`add_compile_options(-std=c++11)`

Comment: Only available from cmake 3.0

Comment: This causes warning and errors when compiling C files in the same project.

Comment: Absolutely do not do this. It will break compiling plain C programs. It glues your CMakeLists.txt to a particular compiler and there's built-in support for this, anyway.

Comment: This fails for the Visual Studio compiler. See my answer for the better answer that works for all the compilers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69804542/7910299

Answer (score 14):

This is another way of enabling C++11 support,

```
ADD_DEFINITIONS(
    -std=c++11 # Or -std=c++0x
    # Other flags
)
```

I have encountered instances where only this method works and other methods fail. Maybe it has something to do with the latest version of CMake.

Comment: That will only work if you are ONLY using C++ compiler. If you're also using the CC compiler it will fail.

Comment: `add_definitions` is only supposed to used for adding DEFINITIONS, i.e. -D SOMETHING. And as @Emmanuel said, it does not work in many cases.

Comment: I used that before but had problems when I included a C file because `add_definitions` was not made for setting flags.

Answer (score 6):

Modern cmake offers simpler ways to configure compilers to use a specific version of C++. The only thing anyone needs to do is set the relevant target properties. Among the [properties supported by cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html#target-properties), the ones that are used to determine how to configure compilers to support a specific version of C++ are the following:

- [`CXX_STANDARD`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html) sets the C++ standard whose features are requested to build the target. Set this as `11` to target C++11.
- [`CXX_EXTENSIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_EXTENSIONS.html), a boolean specifying whether compiler specific extensions are requested.  Setting this as `Off` disables support for any compiler-specific extension.

To demonstrate, here is a minimal working example of a `CMakeLists.txt`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

project(testproject LANGUAGES CXX )

set(testproject_SOURCES
    main.c++
    )

add_executable(testproject ${testproject_SOURCES})

set_target_properties(testproject
    PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 11
    CXX_EXTENSIONS off
    )
```

Answer (score 5):

What works for me is to set the following line in your CMakeLists.txt:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
```

Setting this command activates the C++11 features for the compiler and after executing the `cmake ..` command, you should be able to use `range based for loops` in your code and compile it without any errors.

Comment: This is in the end the best answer if you want exactly `-std=c++11`, as `set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)` will use the flag `-std=gnu++11`, which might be undesirable.

Comment: @Antonio `set (CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)`

Answer (score 5):

In case you want to always activate the latest C++ standard, here's my extension of [David Grayson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31010221/671366), in light of the recent (CMake 3.8 and CMake 3.11) additions of values of 17 and 20 for CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD):

```
IF (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS "3.8")
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
ELSEIF (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS "3.11")
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
ELSE()
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
ENDIF()

# Typically, you'll also want to turn off compiler-specific extensions:
SET(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
```

(Use that code in the place of `set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)` in the linked answer.)

Answer (score 3):

In case you stumble on that same error using cmake as i did.
You need to set

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

to activate threading because it is only supported from c++11 ++

hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

I think just these two lines are enough.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
```

Comment: This makes sense when all targets in a project use the same C++ standard (all compiled libraries and executables use C++11, for example). Otherwise, the Cmake `target_compile_features` function, applied for each individual target, as shown in other answers, is a more recommended approach.

Comment: Given the first line there is absolutely no need for the second, which does nothing but add a redundant flag on compatible compilers and break the build on others (like MSVC).

Answer (score 2):

The modern way is to specify the **minimum required** standard to C++11 with:

```
target_compile_features(foo PUBLIC cxx_std_11)
```

This way:

- CMake can honor default C++ standard of the compiler if it's greater than C++11
- You can clearly specify whether C++ standard is required at build time, consume time, or both. This is nice for libraries.
- Public compile features are propagated to downstream targets, so it comes for free in those targets even if they don't directly use this feature.
- Users can externally set another C++ standard (more recent basically), with `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD`, either from command line or CMake presets. If you hardcode `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` in a CMakeLists, nobody can override the C++ standard without editing your CMakeLists, which is not very pleasant.

It requires CMake >= 3.8

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following. This automatically modifies the feature based on your environment.

```
target_compile_features(your_target INTERFACE cxx_std_20)
```

For example,

- on Gnu/Linux the following adds `-std=gnu++20`
- on Windows with Clang/Ninja it becomes `-std=c++20`
- on Windows with MSVC it becomes `/std=c++20`

So you support as many as environments possible.

Answer (score -6):

OS X and Homebrew LLVM related:

Don't forget to call cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3) and project() after it!

Or CMake will insert `project()` implicitly before line 1, causing trouble with Clang version detection and possibly other sorts of troubles. Here is [a related issue](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=15943).

Comment: The question is not OSX or LVVM related, specifically. Also, there's no reason to require CMake v3.x for C++11 development. As for clang version detection - that's not what OP asked about.