# How to detect C++11 support of a compiler with CMake

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake

Is there a way to let CMake detect automatically if a compiler supports C++11 or not?

As it would be nice to inform the users during the CMake run that the code will not compile as the compiler does not support C++11. At the moment I set the C++11 flags. However, if a compiler does not support it the user gets compile errors instead of an error during the CMake run.

Perfect would be something that works like `find_package()`. However, I have not found any module or function which provides the functionality needed.

Additional it would be nice to have the feature to detect if the compiler needs the flags `std=c++0x` or `std=c++11`.

Is there something available or do I need to develop this on my own?

Below is some code I use so far, however it works only with GNU'c GCC compilers. It would be nice if there would be a more general solution.

```
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
   execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER} -dumpversion OUTPUT_VARIABLE GCC_VERSION)
   if (GCC_VERSION VERSION_GREATER 4.7 OR GCC_VERSION VERSION_EQUAL 4.7)
        message(STATUS "C++11 activated.")
        add_definitions("-std=gnu++11")
   elseif(GCC_VERSION VERSION_GREATER 4.3 OR GCC_VERSION VERSION_EQUAL 4.3)
        message(WARNING "C++0x activated. If you get any errors update to a compiler which fully supports C++11")
        add_definitions("-std=gnu++0x")
   else ()
        message(FATAL_ERROR "C++11 needed. Therefore a gcc compiler with a version higher than 4.3 is needed.")   
   endif()
else(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
   add_definitions("-std=c++0x") 
endif(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
```

Comment: Why use `add_definitions` command instead of setting `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` to set compiler options?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

If you have CMake version 3.1.0 or later you can detect what C++ features
your C++ compiler supports

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0 FATAL_ERROR)
project(foobar CXX)
message("Your C++ compiler supports these C++ features:")
foreach(i ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FEATURES})
  message("${i}")
endforeach()
```

But normally you don't need to use the CMake variable **CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FEATURES** in your CMake scripts. Instead there are two ways of how to tell CMake under which C++ standard your C++ files should be compiled, either by
specifying the C++ standard explicitly or by specifying the required C++ features and let CMake induce the C++ standard. CMake will make sure the C++ compiler is invoked with the correct command line flags (e.g. -std=c++11).

1. Specifying the C++ standard explicitly

---

You could specify the C++ standard explicitly, by setting the CMake properties
[**CXX_STANDARD**](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html)
and
[**CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED**](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED.html) for your CMake target.

```
$ cat /tmp/src/CMakeLists.txt
project(foobar CXX)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0 FATAL_ERROR)
add_executable(prog main.cc)
set_property(TARGET prog PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
set_property(TARGET prog PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
$ cat /tmp/src/main.cc
int main() {
  return 0;
}
$ mkdir /tmp/build
$ cd /tmp/build
$ cmake /tmp/src
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/build
$ make VERBOSE=1 | grep main.cc | grep -- "-c"
/usr/bin/c++    -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles/prog.dir/main.cc.o -c /tmp/src/main.cc
$
```

2. Specifying the required C++ features and let CMake induce the C++ standard

---

You could use the CMake command [**target_compile_features**](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_features.html) to specify the C++ features that are made use of in your CMake target. From this list CMake will induce the C++ standard to be used. The CMake global property [**CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES**](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES.html) lists the C++ features you can choose from.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0 FATAL_ERROR)
message("Your CMake version supports these C++ features:")
get_property(known_features GLOBAL PROPERTY CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES)
foreach(i ${known_features})
  message("${i}")
endforeach()
```

For example, this C++ program with the filename **main.cc** makes use of the C++11 features:
**cxx_strong_enums**, **cxx_constexpr**, **cxx_auto_type**

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  enum class Color { Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue, Violet };
  constexpr float a = 3.1415f;
  auto b = a;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This CMakeLists.txt file would build it

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0 FATAL_ERROR)
project(foobar CXX)
add_executable(foobar main.cc)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
set(needed_features
    cxx_strong_enums
    cxx_constexpr
    cxx_auto_type)
target_compile_features(foobar PRIVATE ${needed_features})
```

Comment: Thanks @MarcGlisse, I have now updated my answer. Instead of **FindCXXFeatures** it now makes use of **target_compile_features**.

Comment: It is a bit painful that this has to be done per target. It would be convenient to say "just use C++11 everywhere" and be done with it.

Comment: It seems to me that the first way is always better since you don't have to remember and look up the cxx11 feature you used in your program.

Comment: Seems like `CXX_STANDARD 11` does not work with `GLOBAL` property scope, which totally sucks.

Comment: @MarcGlisse @abergmeier To define it in the current CMake scope, you can `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)`

Comment: I don't know why, but `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` overwrites `CXX_STANDARD`. I have to set `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)` directly (as @typ1232 already mentioned). Why is it?

Comment: I still got some problems with this approach since it adds `-std=gnu++11` and enables non-standard extensions. I'd really only like `std=c++11` and get an error if I try to use one of these non standard extensions, portability first.

Comment: How to make a feature set default for all further targets?

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl I asked this question and got an answer. see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38132793/1695375). Basically you use 
SET( CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF ).

Comment: For others coming across this answer, there's a full article that goes through this whole area [here](https://crascit.com/2015/03/28/enabling-cxx11-in-cmake/), including discussion of choosing between the two approaches outlined in the above answer and handling of compiler extensions. Disclaimer: I wrote the linked article.

Comment: Be aware that `CXX_STANDARD` does **not** work on MSVC, so basically you have to fall back to `target_compile_features` if you want something that works cross-platform.

Answer (score 40):

At this point, CMake does not have a convenient form to support C++11. Ideally, you would specify a C++11 project like this:

```
project(foo CXX11)
```

at the beginning of your `CMakeLists.txt`. But the `CXX11` project type does not exist (yet). Until then, you may use a two-staged technique:

1. Determine the compiler type and version
2. Adjust build flags accordingly.

For example, this is what I use to support C++11 with Clang and GCC:

```
# Initialize CXXFLAGS.
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS                "-Wall -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG          "-O0 -g")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL     "-Os -DNDEBUG")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE        "-O4 -DNDEBUG")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "-O2 -g")

# Compiler-specific C++11 activation.
if ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" MATCHES "GNU")
    execute_process(
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} -dumpversion OUTPUT_VARIABLE GCC_VERSION)
    if (NOT (GCC_VERSION VERSION_GREATER 4.7 OR GCC_VERSION VERSION_EQUAL 4.7))
        message(FATAL_ERROR "${PROJECT_NAME} requires g++ 4.7 or greater.")
    endif ()
elseif ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" MATCHES "Clang")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -stdlib=libc++")
else ()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Your C++ compiler does not support C++11.")
endif ()
```

Comment: It has now been more than six months since your answer, do you know of any updates? It seems strange that this issue isn't resolved yet.

Comment: Unfortunately I am still not aware of any better solution. Maybe it helps to raise this concern on the CMake mailing list.

Comment: Hi Jack and Matthias,
I know this comment is very late, but it looks like some C++11 support was finally added to CMake:
http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=13842
My understanding is that this will be a part of CMake 3.1, which is scheduled for release in the beginning of November.

Comment: Cool, once this becomes more mainstream I'll update the answer. It looks like one can now associate the C++ version with a CMake target via `set_property(TARGET tgt PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)`.

Comment: @LucasB, true that, but Eric already provides a much nicer answer, which the OP should probably accept at this point.

Comment: Honestly, depending on CMake 3.1 might not be a good idea yet. For example, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS does not provide CMake 3.x for example.

Answer (score 9):

At the time of this writing [(pre-GCC 4.8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13383124/g-std-c0x-and-compatibility), it may not be a good idea to detect C++11 flags and add them.  This is because changing the standard (at least for GCC) [breaks ABI compatibility](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Cxx11AbiCompatibility), which can result in link errors.

Therefore, the use of the C++11 standard should explicitly specified with the compiler setting during the [initial CMake configuration of the project](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#I_change_CMAKE_C_COMPILER_in_the_GUI_but_it_changes_back_on_the_next_configure_step._Why.3F), e.g.

`CXX='g++ -std=c++11' cmake /path/to/source`

That is, the use of -std=c++11 should be treated like a separate compiler, which should not be mixed or changed in a project.

Comment: Now that we are post-GCC 4.8, is the situation the same?

Comment: Essentially, yes.  Or a compiler definition may need to be added, etc.  More information for GCC 5 is here: https://developerblog.redhat.com/2015/02/05/gcc5-and-the-c11-abi/

Answer (score 8):

Use:

```
include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++11" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++0x" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
if(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
elseif(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x")
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Compiler ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} has no C++11 support.")
endif()
```

This is from *[Enabling C++11 (C++0x) in CMake](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2014/01/05/enabling-c11-c0x-in-cmake/)* with minor changes.

Comment: Hello! Unfortunately, your solution only works for compilers that support specified flags for setting C++ standard version. In case of a compiler that supports C++11 but does not support those flags, your solution will give a false negative. For example, MS VS 2015 will not pass.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using CMake 3.8 or newer, you can use the feature `cxx_std_11`, which requests *C++11 or above*:

```
target_compile_features(Hello PUBLIC cxx_std_11)
```

---

In CMake 3.1* and newer, the proper, simple way to do this is to use the `CXX_STANDARD` property for a given target. For example, given this simple example using `auto` (named `main.cpp`):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    auto num = 10;
    std::cout << num << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The following `CMakeLists.txt` will enable C++11 support:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(Hello CXX)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(Hello ${SOURCE_FILES})

set_property(TARGET Hello PROPERTY
    CXX_STANDARD 11
    CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON
)
```

This will add any flags necessary such as `-std=c++11`. Note that the `CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED` property will prevent the standard from decaying to an earlier version.

---

Another proper but not as simple way to specify the `CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES` that you use, such as `cxx_auto_type`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(Hello CXX)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(Hello ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_compile_features(Hello PRIVATE cxx_auto_type)
```

---

<sub>* I have not tried this on CMake 3.1, but have verified it works in CMake 3.3. The [documentation for 3.1](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html) does document this so it should work.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

We've written a CMake module for detecting and enabling C++11 support which you can find here:
https://github.com/NitroShare/CXX11-CMake-Macros

It's still a work-in-progress, but we are using it for a number of Qt projects that target Windows/Linux/Mac. Currently only MSVC++, GCC, and Clang are supported.

**Example:**

```
include(CXX11)

check_for_cxx11_compiler(CXX11_COMPILER)

# If a C++11 compiler is available, then set the appropriate flags
if(CXX11_COMPILER)
    enable_cxx11()
endif()
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting the principle of [Erik Sjölund](https://stackoverflow.com/users/757777/erik-sj%c3%b6lund)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20165220) to better effect:

For CMake versions 3.3 and later, use:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3 FATAL_ERROR)
project(foo CXX)
if("cxx_std_11" IN_LIST CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FEATURES)
  # Do something assuming C++11 can be used
endif()
```

No need to use `foreach` and such.

Note: Naturally, you can do this with C++17,  C++20 and non-standard-version features.