# initializer_list: No such file or directory

Tags: c++

I want to include matrix library to my project, but when i include matrix.h and matrix.hpp here are  errors :

```
 initializer_list: No such file or directory
 error: tuple: No such file or directory
error: type_traits: No such file or directory
```

Lines

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <tuple>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
```

truble it. Help,plz. I think here is some kind of problem with standards

gcc 4.8; Mac OS

Comment: Your compiler doesn't yet support C++11 library feature - `initializer_list`. Update.

Comment: It compiles another program with this include

Comment: Then check the documentation on how to enable C++11. Which compiler is it?

Comment: which matrix library are you using?

Comment: Which compiler ? For example with `gcc`, it is possible that the other program has the option `-std=c++11`. If you don't have this option in your compilation line, you don't have the c++11 features...

Comment: gcc 4.8 as i remember; Mac OS, but i have tried on Ubuntu: the same

Comment: Can you provide the command line you are using to compile the program? Or are you using a makefile? If yes, can we see it?

Comment: @user2897535: Questions are editable. Please edit the compiler and platform information _into the question_.

Comment: I have to use makefile which was done by CMake 2.8-12

Comment: @user2897535: Than that CMakeLists.txt would be relevant.

Comment: http://codepaste.ru/15658/ here is that makefile

Comment: http://codepaste.ru/15659/ here is CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using **GCC-4.8** and your problem is that you don't have the **C++11** features try to add `-std=c++11` to your compilation line.

I saw that you are using CMake, then [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10852679/1394283) may help you (you can replace `-std=c++0x` by `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11`).

Example:

```
# It appends the -std=c++11 option to CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11") # for gcc >= 4.7

# Or
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x") # for gcc < 4.7
```

Comment: I have 
'code'SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O2 -Wno-unused-value")'code'
when i change it to
'code'SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O2 -Wno-unused-value")'code'
it answers 
'code'  unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11" 'code'

Comment: @user2897535: You may need `-std=c++0x` (rather than `c++11`) on older versions of GCC; but I would have thought that 4.8 would understand `c++11`.

Comment: it doesn't understand -std=c++0x  too. I think i write it in a wrong way, but i dont know the right one.

Comment: @user2897535 and you have the same error? Are you sure you use gcc? I thought that CMake was using `clang` on MacOSX by default... [**This**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11004675/1394283) may be useful.