# compiling CMake with multiple -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS options

Tags: cmake, compiler-flags

I am compiling CMake with some default options, the first is `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++11`.

Other compiles using CMake are complaining with warnings of needing C++14 as well.

Is it possible to have add multiple options to this flag such as `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++11:c++14`

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot pass multiple options for C++ flags.
What would be the meaning of your example anyway? Use C++11 or C++14, whatever is available? If both are applicable, use the higher one? Either you use C++11 or C++14 features, then you need the compiler to be at least in the right mode.

If you write your own CMakeLists.txt for your project, you can either use CMake for checking supported C++1/C++14 features or you [can try accepted flags and choose the most recent one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20166663).
For recent CMake versions, you can set the required C++ mode per target via the `CXX_STANDARD` properte, see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html

Comment: I have two dependencies being compiled for a 3rd program, one needs c++11, the other c++14, so based on your response it seems I need two cmake builds.

Comment: Why not build both third party programs with C++14?

Comment: I am going on the release notes that c++11 MUST be set for the first and that c++14 features are needed for the 2nd. I have no insight into why the first MUST have c++11, hence my question. I will try both with C++14 and hope that there are no unforeseen issues by using a higher version. thx Art.