# How to load thread support in C++ with cmake and Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, multithreading, android-ndk, cmake

I have a problem using threads in my application. I am writing C++ files, that are used in Android, so they are compiled with NDK and cmake. I have no idea how to load thread support. Is there anything i have to write into CMakeLists or the MakeFile or something like that? I am  an absolute beginner in writing C++ code...

Comment: This is the code i get after the make, after including <thread>:C:/android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.

Comment: Did you try adding one of the flags that were suggested to you?

Comment: I don't know exactly how to do it... I also read somewhere, that with compiler version 4.6 you have to do anything else...

Comment: Add it to `LOCAL_CPPFLAGS` in your Android.mk

Comment: C++ offers native multi threading support since C++ 11, you'll need GCC 4.8 to reach such level of features (maybe 4.7?).
You can refer to [this other SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984442/how-to-detect-c11-support-of-a-compiler-with-cmake) for further details on that.

Comment: Maybe i really don't know what i am doing, but i dont have a Android.mk. I am writing C++ files and i do compile them with cmake and the NDK cpp compiler... The files run on Android, but don't communicate directly with any Java code, so there is no JNI used. These files are only loaded by a HMI software on the Android system.

Comment: Do the C++ files you're writing allow you to use pthreads features instead, or does it have to be the C++ <thread>?

Comment: I think i can use pthreads too, but i don't get them working as well... the main task of my C++ code is to listen and write to a socket, so which type of thread i use is not important in my opinion... The main things in my architecture happen in java, so i want to have the C++ part as simple as possible, because i don't really know anything about C++ coding..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using **Cmake** for Android, e.g. https://github.com/taka-no-me/android-cmake, then to enable `std::thread` you should specify

```
ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_NAME=arm-linux-androideabi-4.8
```

and

```
ANDROID_STL=gnustl_static
```

(or `gnustl_shared`),

Answer (score 0):

To enable C++11 thread class (`std::thread`) with Cmake simply add to your `CMakeLists.txt` the following line:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -Werror")
```

Full example [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/master/camera/basic/src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt).