# Forcing C99 in CMake (to use 'for' loop initial declaration)

Tags: c++, c, cmake, c99

I've been searching a portable way to force CMake to enable the compiler's C99 features in order to avoid the following `gcc` error for instance:

```
error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
for (int s = 1; s <= in_para->StepNumber; s++){
^
```

I also wouldn't like to check for which compiler and append something like:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-std=c99") # that would be bad
```

So I found this post: [Enabling C99 in CMake](http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/Enabling-C99-in-CMake-td6505762.html) and the associated feature request: [0012300: CMake has no cross-platform way to ask for C99](http://www.cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=12300). In this Mantis bug I learned about [`target_compiler_features`](http://www.steveire.com/cmake-future/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html#manual:cmake-compile-features%287%29) and after that I found these SOF answers on it: [How to activate C++11 in CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20165519/1254880) and [How to detect C++11 support of a compiler with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20165220/1254880).

So my questions are: this `target_compiler_features` will provide a way to require a C feature as well as a C++ one? What is the most portable way to achive this by now - I'm currently using CMake 2.8.12.2. The `target_compiler_features` isn't in CMake's most recent release version (3.0.0). Do you know when it is being released?

Comment: What's so bad about `-std=c99`?  That's the way I'd do it.  You probably don't have more than two different ways you need to support for different compilers (e.g. Clang and GCC are the same).

Comment: I would like something that would work for both gcc and MSVC without having to check for CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID. By the way, I also use -std=c99, but it seems that there is / there will be a better approach with target_compiler_features.

Comment: Maybe someday there will be something better.  I'm not sure what your question is then.  This isn't a release-date forecasting site for CMake.

Comment: Well, I was wondering if there would be a chance some cmake dev notices this question. Also, as the bug report I cite is already three years old I was also hoping that someone have already figured out some better approach. Also, there are some answers on this future feature but only dealing with C++11, so I'm asking if it will apply also to C (as I'm not willing to read the code and/or draft documentation of it).

Comment: It sounds like you should ask the CMake devs directly using their preferred method of contact (perhaps a mailing list), rather than hoping one of them stumbles upon this.

Comment: As far as I know MSVC simply doesn't implement C99.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/07/19/c99-library-support-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx) may help

Comment: @chux, this only talks about C library support, not about the core language or the preprocessor.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

After creating a target such as a library or executable, put a line like this in your CMakeLists.txt file:

```
set_property(TARGET tgt PROPERTY C_STANDARD 99)
```

where `tgt` is the name of your target.

I think this was added in CMake 3.1, and the documentation is here:

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/C_STANDARD.html

If you need to support versions of CMake older than 3.1, you can use this macro:

```
macro(use_c99)
  if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS "3.1")
    if (CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "GNU")
      set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-std=gnu99 ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}")
    endif ()
  else ()
    set (CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
  endif ()
endmacro(use_c99)
```

After putting that macro in your top-level file so it is visible everywhere, you can just write `use_c99()` at the top of any CMakeLists file that defines a target with C99 code in it.

### CMake issue #15943 for clang users targeting macOS

If you are using CMake and clang to target MacOS there is a [bug](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/15943) that can cause the `CMAKE_C_STANDARD` feature to simply not work (not add any compiler flags).  Make sure that you do one of the following things:

- Use [cmake_minimum_required](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_minimum_required.html) to require CMake 3.0 or later, or
- Set policy CMP0025 to NEW with the following code at the top of your CMakeLists.txt file before the `project` command:

  ```
    # Fix behavior of CMAKE_C_STANDARD when targeting macOS.
    if (POLICY CMP0025)
      cmake_policy(SET CMP0025 NEW)
    endif ()
  ```

Answer (score 7):

As this question keeps getting attention I'm summarizing here what I think are the best options today.

The following command sets C99 as a minimum requirement for `target`:

```
target_compile_features(target PUBLIC c_std_99)
```

I consider this the preferred way, as it is per target and exposes a way to control the visibility through the `PUBLIC`, `INTERFACE` and `PRIVATE` keywords - see [the reference](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_features.html). Although the `target_compile_features` command was introduced on the 3.1 version, `c_std_99` requires at least [CMake 3.8](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/prop_gbl/CMAKE_C_KNOWN_FEATURES.html).

Similar to the above, another way to set C99 as the standard for `target` is the following:

```
set_property(TARGET target PROPERTY C_STANDARD 99)
```

This is available since CMake 3.1. A possible drawback is that it doesn't enforce the standard (see [the reference](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/C_STANDARD.html)). For this reason setting the `C_STANDARD_REQUIRED` property may be useful:

```
set_property(TARGET target PROPERTY C_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
```

The above two properties are defaulted to the values of [`CMAKE_C_STANDARD`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_C_STANDARD.html) and [`CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/C_STANDARD_REQUIRED.html) respectively.

So a possible way to make C99 default for all targets is:

```
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED TRUE)
```

---

As a side note, expanding on the `target_compile_features` approach, there may be no need to require some specific language standard if all you care about is some specific feature. For instance by setting:

```
target_compile_features(target PUBLIC c_variadic_macros)
```

CMake will take care to pick the proper flags that enforce the availability of variadic macros. However currently there are only a few such features available for the C language - see [CMAKE_C_KNOWN_FEATURES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/CMAKE_C_KNOWN_FEATURES.html) for the complete list - and loop initial declarations is not among them.

Answer (score 0):

In libevent, add the following in CMakeLists.txt

```
set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-std=gnu99 ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}")
```

Comment: Please explain in more detail, why that is the correct answer.

Comment: This does not work for all compilers and might clash with user setting, leading to multiple std commands in the compiler invocation - which is very confusing.

Answer (score -1):

Edit CMakeLists

add on line > 2

```
set (CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
```

then

```
cmake 3 ..
```

Answer (score -1):

The [C_STANDARD property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/C_STANDARD.html) will allow use to apply the C standard to a specific target, rather than globally. The following will apply C99 to `mytarget`.

```
set_property(TARGET mytarget PROPERTY C_STANDARD 99)
```

Answer (score -2):

From CMake 3.0.2, it is possible to use add_compile_options (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_options.html#command:add_compile_options), it is one of the most portable way I found to set C standart.

Take care to use this command before to declare target (with add_library or add_executable).

Below is a CMake script example setting C standart to C99:

```
add_compile_options(-std=c99)
add_executable(my_exe ${SOURCES})
```

Comment: Maybe you're considering only CMake version 3.0? Because this cannot be the most portable way starting with CMake 3.8, which enable setting `target_compile_features` to c_std_99. For instance -std=c99 will break MSVC builds, for which there's no analog way of requiring C99 standard (but accept a C11 specification with /std:c11).

Comment: @Tarc : The problem of target_compile_features and more in general Cmake Compile Features is that these properties don't work with all compiler.
They works only with these compiler:
A. For C++ standard: Cray Compiler Environment version 8.1+, PGI version 12.10+, IBM XL version 10.1+.

B. For C standard: all compilers and versions listed above with only meta-features for C++, Texas Instruments compiler. [source](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html#supported-compilers)

Answer (score -3):

Add the following to your CMakeLists.txt file and run cmake again

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "std=c99")
```

Comment: @SeanBurton good point, at the same time, I think a lot of people use SO like I do, skipping directly to the answers, so FWIW I found the answer here, not in OP :) (of course I would have scrutinized OP eventually!)