# Cmake won't set the compiler standard to c++11?

Tags: cmake

I'm new to cmake, and I was building some c++11 code with it (notably a set of template aliases.) I want to use the [CXX_STANDARD](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html) property to hopefully cover all platforms and problems introduced by simply adding -std=c++11 to cxxflags, which worked for me before:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
```

But when I change this to

```
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED true)
```

cmake doesn't tell the compiler to use c++11. What am I doing wrong with the latter code?

Comment: May be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984442/how-to-detect-c11-support-of-a-compiler-with-cmake) will help you?

Comment: Thanks, I had already seen that, but on inspecting it more carefully I realized that the more or less valid code I produced above needs at least cmake version 3.1, where I was running version 2.8. I upgraded and it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD is not a global property, but a variable.
http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/variable/CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD.html#variable:CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD

So all you need is

```
set( CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11 )
```

before you define any targets.

Answer (score 6):

I didn't have CMake updated to the latest version... I should have done that before posting a question. The code above only works for version > 3.1.