# GCC/G++ : Enable -std=c++11 from environment variable

Tags: c++11, gcc, g++

I have some OpenCV/C++ application which compiles with a CMake definitions file, in which I did not find a way to pass flags to the compiler.

I know that there are the flags C_INCLUDE_PATH CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH, and all the rest of their friends...

But, is there an environment variable for definition of any other flags, in which I'd be able to define `-std=c++11` ?

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851247/how-to-activate-c-11-in-cmake) solve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest but certainly not nicest solution if you want to force it by hand would be:

```
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)
```

However CMake should be able to pick the necessary standard for you. Have a look to this answer:
[How to detect c++11 support of a compiler with cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984442/how-to-detect-c11-support-of-a-compiler-with-cmake/20165220#20165220)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using CMake, equally easy and nicer solution will be to pass

```
-DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=11 -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED=ON
```

to CMake.