# cmake: Specify c++14 when using gcc < 4.7

Tags: gcc, cmake

What is the directive for specifying C++14 in CMake?

CMake, gcc, and g++ version are given below:

gcc: 4.6.3

g++: 4.6.3

CMake: 2.8.7

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851247/how-to-activate-c-11-in-cmake

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to control compiler flag invoked when specifing CMAKE\_CXX\_STANDARD?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132793/how-to-control-compiler-flag-invoked-when-specifing-cmake-cxx-standard)

Comment: I am not sure that g++ 4.6.3 has any c++14 features at all. Ok i am pretty sure it does not. You compiler is too old for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to wrap this up, as @Hayt pointed out in a comment, g++ 4.6.3 doesn't support the c++14 standard.

For more information on the supported languages, see [this post on gcc.gnu.org](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx14)