# C++11 activation with <target_compile_feature> or <set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)>

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake

I'm using a Python library, named [PyPHS](https://github.com/pyphs/pyphs), specialized in physical modeling.
To save computation during the simulation, it implements a C++ code generation feature. It uses CMake to generate an executable of a particular simulation.

It is implemented in C++ 11.

---

**Issue**

In the CMakeLists.txt file, the C++ 11 feature is activated by the following line:

```
target_compile_features(<project_name> PUBLIC cxx_std_11)
```

On my computer (CMake 3.5.1 & Ubuntu 16.04.4 Xenial Xerus), CMake throws an error: this feature is unknown:

````
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:31 (target_compile_features):
  target_compile_features specified unknown feature "cxx_std_11" for target
  "dampedosc".
```

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/victorw/git/vocal-phs/python/output/dampedosc/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
````

### This error has not been encountered on other installs (Debian 8, Mac OSX or windows 7)

**Fix**

I’ve changed the CMakeLists.txt template. Here is the link to the commit, on my own fork of [PyPHS](https://github.com/WetzelVictor/pyphs/commit/badbc7cf396f9d4cf8f991bc07dea4c9e3f34f1e).

I’ve replaced the `target_compile_features(<project_name> PUBLIC cxx_std_11)` by `set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)`

---

**Question**

What is the difference between the two commands?
What are your insights on this matter? Did I forget to mention some information?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984442/how-to-detect-c11-support-of-a-compiler-with-cmake/20165220#20165220

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `cxx_std_11` compiler meta-feature is not available in your version of `CMake`. it was introduced in `3.8`, so this would explain the error, [CMake 3.8 release notes](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/release/3.8.html#c-c).

The difference between the two is that `target_compile_features()` can request specific features for a specific target. CMake will automatically apply the appropriate standard to the specified target. If you on the other hand set `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD`, then the requested standard, if supported by CMake, is applied project wide (for all targets).

As mentioned, you can as of `CMake 3.8` request an entire standard using `target_compile_features()`, in which case the only difference from setting `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` is that the standard is only applied to the specified target (read below).

Note that if you invoke `target_compile_features` with `PRIVATE` scope, then the requested features/standard will apply **only** to the specified target, if instead `PUBLIC` is set, then the requested features/standard will also be applied to any target that depend on that target.

Comment: just note that you also have target properties: [CXX_STANDARD](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html),
[CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED.html),
[CXX_EXTENSIONS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_EXTENSIONS.html)