# How to detect if VS C++ compiler supports C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, macros

How to detect if Visual Studio (VS) C++ compiler supports C++11 through preprocessor macros? I tried with `__cplusplus` (the preprocessor macro that many people advise to use for this kind of checks) but it fails with VS C++ 2010 compiler (i.e. function `get_dimension` is never declared):

```
#if __cplusplus > 199711L
    int get_dimension(int index);
#endif
```

Comment: Perhaps a better question would be why are you using a 10-year old Visual Studio version?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: perhaps... but it does not invalidate the original question posted here! :)

Comment: What do you mean "it fails". Isn't it supposed to not declare that function for compilers that don't support C++11? Seems like a success to me.

Comment: Here is a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047971/how-do-i-check-for-c11-support

Comment: Why would you expect a compiler released in 2010 to fully support C++11 (formalised in 2011)?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: most of the time, because the client use a 10-year old version. In my case, our client requires compatibility with gcc 4.1.* ;-)

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10984442/3378179

Comment: @Caduchon quite often that happens because the client doesn't know that newer versions are actually free, eg by downloading a fresh Windows SDK, Visual Studio Code, or a Community version of Visual Studio. Or are afraid that newer C++ versions will break older code and don't want to test

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, yeah. But it could be difficult to change in a short time. In our case, they require compatibility with gcc4.1 for cross-platform comilation on all linux configurations (if I well understood) of a sofware where we add a library.

Answer (score 2):

You can check with [`_MSVC_LANG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=vs-2019) macro out of the box.

`__cplusplus` is the language multi compiler *ivory tower* kind of solution, but unfortunately has to be enabled in `MSVC` before it can be used meaningfully (and may not be supported in very old versions). This is fantastic for people using eg. `gcc` where its set up with the version by default (and most of those people will believe it to work on `MSVC` as well). So only if you need to support many compilers would I worry, and even then I would consider to add special check for some compilers, namely `MSVC`.

[C++ team blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-now-correctly-reports-__cplusplus/)

Comment: And for their current compiler, it should be fine: [MSVC now correctly reports `__cplusplus`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-now-correctly-reports-__cplusplus/)

Comment: @TedLyngmo good point, and good to hear - unfortunately it does not help alot currently because it doesn't go back in time - maybe in 5 or 10 years.

Comment: Indeed - we'll have to live with it for a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `#if __cplusplus >= 201103L` instead to check if a compiler is 100% C++11 compliant. If it's false then the compiler doesn't support C++11 or only supports a subset of it

Now if you just need to use *some specific features in C++11* then you can [use Boost to check it](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/boost_macro_reference.html#boost_config.boost_macro_reference.macros_that_describe_c__11_features_not_supported). For example if you need `constexpr` support then use

```
#ifndef BOOST_NO_CXX11_CONSTEXPR
```

You can also use some [macros that allow the use of C++11 features with C++03 compilers](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/boost_macro_reference.html#boost_config.boost_macro_reference.macros_that_allow_use_of_c__11_features_with_c__03_compilers) like `BOOST_CONSTEXPR`

But the better solution is to exclude ancient compilers completely with `_MSC_VER` or `_MSC_FULL_VER`

```
#if _MSC_VER > 1600
```