# Add C++0x support in CMake

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake

I have a rather large application configured in CMake. I have recently added a couple of classes that use C++0x functionality, and it breaks the build, since CMake is not configured to compile with C++0x support. How do I add that as an option to CMake?

Comment: If you are using newer compiler, you should use `-std=c++11` instead. It's no longer a draft.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add the flag to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x")
```

Answer (score 7):

I use this snippet for GCC, but it is a more complicated way:

```
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
   SET(ENABLE_CXX11 "-std=c++11")

   EXECUTE_PROCESS(COMMAND "${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} -dumpversion" OUTPUT_VARIABLE GCC_VERSION)
   if (GCC_VERSION VERSION_LESS 4.7)
      SET(ENABLE_CXX11 "-std=c++0x")
   endif()

   SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${ENABLE_CXX11}")
endif()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the following module:

```
$ cat FindCXX11.cmake
# - Finds if the compiler has C++11 support
# This module can be used to detect compiler flags for using C++11, and checks
# a small subset of the language.
#
# The following variables are set:
#   CXX11_FLAGS - flags to add to the CXX compiler for C++11 support
#   CXX11_FOUND - true if the compiler supports C++11
#
# TODO: When compilers starts implementing the whole C++11, check the full set

include(CheckCXXSourceCompiles)
include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)

set(CXX11_FLAG_CANDIDATES
    # GNU and Intel Linux
    "-std=c++0x"
    # Microsoft Visual Studio, and everything that automatically accepts C++11
    " "
    #Intel Windows
    "/Qstd=c++0x"
    )

set(CXX11_TEST_SOURCE
"
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix(int a, int b, int c, int d)
        : data {a, b, c, d}
    {}

private:
    int data[4];
};

int main()
{
    int n[] {4,7,6,1,2};
    for (auto i : n)
        Matrix mat (3,5,1,2);
    return 0;
}
")

foreach(FLAG ${CXX11_FLAG_CANDIDATES})
    set(SAFE_CMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS "${CMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS}")
    set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS "${FLAG}")
    unset(CXX11_FLAG_DETECTED CACHE)
    message(STATUS "Try C++11 flag = [${FLAG}]")
    check_cxx_source_compiles("${CXX11_TEST_SOURCE}" CXX11_FLAG_DETECTED)
    set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS "${SAFE_CMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS}")
    if(CXX11_FLAG_DETECTED)
        set(CXX11_FLAGS_INTERNAL "${FLAG}")
        break()
    endif(CXX11_FLAG_DETECTED)
endforeach(FLAG ${CXX11_FLAG_CANDIDATES})

set(CXX11_FLAGS "${CXX11_FLAGS_INTERNAL}")

find_package_handle_standard_args(CXX11 DEFAULT_MSG CXX11_FLAGS)
mark_as_advanced(CXX11_FLAGS)
```

I use this to check if the subset of C++11 I'm using (actually this is redundant now, as I'm using a lot more), is supported by the compiler. It is easy to build this further and add more features, and add other compiler switches. Actually the only compilers I have found so far which passes this test, is GCC >= 4.6 and Clang >= 3.1 if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20165519/648162), it's better to use `target_compile_features` to require support for the specific features that you need.

This explains/documents better what functionality your code requires, is cross-platform compatible, and will give the user a more helpful error message if the required feature is not available in their compiler.

From the [manual page](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/command/target_compile_features.html) for this option:

> ```
> target_compile_features
> ```
>
> Add expected compiler features to a target.
>
> ```
> target_compile_features(<target> <PRIVATE|PUBLIC|INTERFACE> <feature> [...])
> ```
>
> Specify compiler features required when compiling a given target. If
>   the feature is not listed in the CMAKE_C_COMPILE_FEATURES variable or
>   CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FEATURES variable, then an error will be reported by
>   CMake. If the use of the feature requires an additional compiler flag,
>   such as `-std=gnu++11`, the flag will be added automatically.

The (hopefully complete) list of features that can be tested with this macro is [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/prop_gbl/CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES.html#prop_gbl:CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES).