# Qt requires C++11 support

Tags: qt, c++11, gcc, compiler-errors

I used Qt 5.7 and gcc 4.9.2. Qt Core module throw `Qt requires C++11 support` error.

[This page](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_5.7.0_Known_Issues) say that

> gcc 4.9.2 fails to compile Qt.

So I installed gcc 4.8. I check using below command on terminal :

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-1ubuntu15) 4.8.4
```

My kit uses cmake not qmake. I add  `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES ( xxxx yyyy /usr/bin/c++ -std=c++11`  to CMakeLists-txt.

I restart my pc and run my application again. Same error is throwed.

```
/opt/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qbasicatomic.h:61: error: #error "Qt requires C++11 support"
 #  error "Qt requires C++11 support"
    ^
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Did you try using C++11 (e.g. compiler flags)?

Comment: @ray I add TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES ( xxxx yyyy /usr/bin/c++ -std=c++11 to CMakeLists.txt file

Comment: Ah, sorry, I must've missed the part during my first glance at the post.

Comment: `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES` seems to only be about the linking stage. `-std=c++11` must also be added to the compiler options. You might find an answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10851247/894321

Comment: Use `CXX_STANDARD` and `CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED` CMake variables (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html). Manually adding `-std` options will often break your CMake build if different libraries require different standards.

Comment: @Velkan SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")  is fine. It works.

Comment: @zumma, it works on your machine with your config.

Answer (score 4):

If using QtCreator, you can add this to your `.pro` file:

```
CONFIG += c++11
```

https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_use_C%2B%2B11_in_your_Qt_Projects

Answer (score 3):

Its has been a while.
How I finally solve it is indicating in **CMakeLists.txt** the following line just after `project(MyProject)`:

```
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)
```

That says to cmake, to create a **Makefile** that will use c++11 solving issues.

Answer (score 1):

solution for me was (in your .pro file):

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -stdlib=libc++
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -mmacosx-version-min=10.7
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -mmacosx-version-min=10.7
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn c++11 on explicitly:

1. `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11" CACHE STRING "compile flags" FORCE)` after `project(...)` declaration.
2. `add_library(MyLib SHARED ${PROJECT_HEADERS} ${PROJECT_SOURCES})
   ...
   set_property(TARGET MyLib PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
   set_property(TARGET MyLib PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)`

Answer (score 0):

SOMETIMES, this will not be a configuration issue as mentioned in other answers. In my case, the problem was one file that happened to have been saved with a .CPP extension rather than .cpp. QMake (Qt5) was misidentifying the file and trying to compile it with the C compiler rather than the C++ compiler. The QMake from Qt4 was not exhibiting this issue. Renaming the file fixed the issue.

My comment at the time was "Could this really be that f&*%%&* simple!!"

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your answer is rather a comment than an answer. Edit it or delete it.