# How to build Qt project in linux with cmake

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I am using ubuntu 14.04, cmake 2.8.12.2, Qt5.6.2 (a built version), GNU make 3.81

After I run cmake with `cmake PathToSource -G "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles"`
I do `make`. I get `#error "You must build your code with position independent code if Qt was built with -reduce-relocations. " "Compile your code with -fPIC (-fPIE is not enough)."
 #  error "You must build your code with position independent code if Qt was built with -reduce-relocations. "\`

I then download source file of `Qt5.7.0`, build and install it without problem. I do again `cmake PathToSource -G "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles"`, make it. I get many errors, such as `/home/sflee/Documents/Software_dev/3rd_party/Qt5.7.0/include/QtCore/qhash.h:957:10: error: ‘pair’ does not name a type
     auto pair = qAsConst(*this).equal_range(akey);` and `/home/sflee/Documents/Software_dev/3rd_party/Qt5.7.0/include/QtCore/qbasicatomic.h:285:14: error: ‘Ops’ has not been declared
     { return Ops::fetchAndAddRelease(_q_value, valueToAdd); }`

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt 5.7 requires C++11 compiler. If you get that kind of error from `auto pair`, it sounds like your compiler is not compiling C++11 code. There are two possible reasons:

1. You just need to pass `-std=c++11` to your compiler, as explaned [under this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851247/how-to-activate-c-11-in-cmake).
2. You have too old compiler. However, since you compiled Qt 5.7 itself with the same compiler, this shouldn't be the problem for you.

Comment: I build `Qt5.7.0`, with `g++4.8.4`, then I add `-std=c++11`. No more `error: ‘pair’ does not name a type` appear, but then I get `#error "You must build your code with position independent code if Qt was built with -reduce-relocations. " "Compile your code with -fPIC (-fPIE is not enough)."
 #  error "You must build your code with position independent code if Qt was built with -reduce-relocations. "\` again. /.\

Comment: Well, just add `-fPIC` to your project compiler flags, same way you added `-std=c++11`?

Comment: You can also let CMake manage the std flag by itself by using `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)`.