# How to avoid clang-format to format two separate '>' into a shift?

Tags: c++, c++03, clang-format

When I use clang to format my C++ codes, I ran into a problem:

```
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int> > q;
```

will be automatically formatted into:

```
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int>> q;
```

Two separate '>' will be formatted into a shift >>.

So how should I configure the *.clang-format* file to avoid this situation?

Comment: That's not a shift, and since C++11 is syntactically equal as the first.

Comment: that's how it should be formatted

Comment: But this would lead to error: '>>' should be '> >' within a nested template argument list

Comment: It will only be a problem with older compilers. Is that your problem, that you have to use an old pre-C++11 compiler?

Comment: Yes, because I'm submitting code to OJ, it doesn't support C++11.

Comment: A number of bypassers actually need to enable C++11 in a CMake project and go to [c++11 - How to activate C++ 11 in CMake? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851247/how-to-activate-c-11-in-cmake "c++11 - How to activate C++ 11 in CMake? - Stack Overflow").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is the Standard option that you can use. You want the C++03 option (which would include C++98), as that would format double `>` in templates to include a white space in between them.

```
Standard: Cpp03
```

You can even use `Auto` instead so that `clang-format` can auto detect the C++ version used.

Comment: As an addition, the `Standard` option can also be set to `Auto`, in which case it will be formatted as C++11 if it looks like C++11 code, and C++03 otherwise. `Cpp03` (or equivalently, `C++03`) makes more sense in the OP's specific case, but `Auto` could be more appropriate if the OP wants to set it globally.

Comment: @hvd Isn't `Auto` the default? So assuming that OP didn't not know about "Standard", `Auto` didn't work correctly?

Comment: No, the default is `Cpp11`, at least according to my system's `clang-format -dump-config` output.

Comment: @hvd Ahh. Thanks for the info! :)