# QtCreator uses CMAKE_C_FLAGS to interpret c++ (hpp) header

Tags: c++, cmake, qt-creator

we recently ran into a problem that QtCreator fails to interpret hpp header files.
Error messages like
"Expected a function declaration" on `namespace A {` or "Expected ';' got 'class' on `class B {` are shown and the syntax highlighting doesn't work correcltly.

We found out that this issue is related to the following compiler flags:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -std=gnu99")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
```

By deleting the first line (CMAKE_C_FLAGS std=gnu99), QtCreator interprets the herader files correctly.

Somehow QtCreator seems to use CMAKE_C_FLAGS for parsing c++ header files.

Is this maybe a issue with QtCreator? Do we miss something?

Comment: QtCreator should not have anything to say about that. CMake controls the project and what files are passed to gcc.

Answer (score 0):

test this line of code

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

and also use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851247/how-to-activate-c-11-in-cmake)

Comment: Could you explain why and how this answers the question?

Comment: This does not solve the problem, by adding this line we still can't set CMAKE_C_FLAGS to -std=gnu99 without destroying syntax highlighting in QtCreator