# Can I keep GoogleTest-build from modifying the global CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS variable?

Tags: cmake, c++17, googletest

My *C++* project is built with *CMake* and includes tests utilizing *GoogleTest*. In order to keep me from compatibility issues between different projects and the installed/compiled *GoogleTest* version, I once decided to have *GoogleTest* always local in my project directories.

I achieved this by having *GoogleTest* downloaded and built as part of my own test project, that includes/links gtest. This looks like this in the respective `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
# Download and unpack googletest at configure time
configure_file(CMakeLists.txt.in googletest-download/CMakeLists.txt)
execute_process(COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -G "${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" .
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-download"
)
execute_process(COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" --build .
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-download"
)
```

In order to have this working there is an external project defined in `CMakeLists.txt.in`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.2)
project(googletest-download NONE)

include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(googletest
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/googletest.git
    GIT_TAG master
    SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-src"
    BINARY_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-build"
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    TEST_COMMAND ""
)
```

So far so good!

This worked quite a while for me, but I run into some trouble, since I started to use *C++17* features in my most recent project. This is a problem because my test project refuses to compile, when it includes code, that makes use of *C++17*.

The reason for this is, that running *GoogleTest*'s CMake build modifies the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable on a global scale. In fact it overrides my definition of the compiler mode:

```
CXX_FLAGS =  -Wall -pedantic -std=c++17   -std=gnu++11
```

... where it should look like this:

```
CXX_FLAGS =  -Wall -pedantic -std=c++17
```

Is there a way to keep *GoogleTest*'s build script from modifying that global variable? Or maybe have it restored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Test project specifies for its targets (`gtest` and `gtest_main`) that they need to be compiled with **at least** C++11 features. This is done with `target_compile_features` command ([googletest/cmake/internal_utils.cmake#L193](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/cmake/internal_utils.cmake#L193)):

```
target_compile_features(${name} PUBLIC cxx_std_11)
```

So, whenever you link with `gtest` or `gtest_main` targets, CMake checks, whether C++11 is already provided by the caller, and if no, adds corresponded compiler flag (`-std=gnu++11` for gcc).

It seems you have added `-std=c++17` directly into `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable. This is a **bad way** for specify the standard: CMake never checks `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` for detect which compiler features are currently enabled.

The correct setting of c++17 implies either setting `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` variable:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
```

or calling `target_compile_features` for your targets:

```
target_compile_features(my_exe PUBLIC cxx_std_17)
```

See more about setting C/C++ standard in CMake in that question: [How do I activate C++ 11 in CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851247/how-do-i-activate-c-11-in-cmake)

Comment: Thx for correcting my inner attitude about setting the standard ;)