# No such file or directory compiling minimalistic cmake example

Tags: c++, cmake

I tried making a minimalistic try to learn how to use cmake with c++. When I tried it my first time, it worked. Then I did it in a second folder and I got compile errors when running make. All I did was run `cmake .` and then `make`. What does the error mean?

#### error

```
Scanning dependencies of target hello
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/hello.dir/main.cc.o
c++: error: g++: No such file or directory
CMakeFiles/hello.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/hello.dir/main.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/hello.dir/main.cc.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/hello.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/hello.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

#### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)  # set version to same as on system
project(hello)  # set project name to something
add_executable(hello main.cc)  # the executable should be called "hello"

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Weffc++")
```

#### main.cc:

```cpp
int main()
{
}
```

Comment: If you `make VERBOSE=1` you're likely to see what what (bad) effect `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` containing `g++` is having on your entire `g++` command-line.

Comment: Remove `g++` from the flag string.

Comment: You're right, it makes sense now. I didn't understand that "g++" was the file it was referring to.

Comment: `-std=c++17` there is  a CMake way to do this. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/52382437/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52382437/487892)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `g++`  from `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`  as you shall pass compiler flags in it.

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "-std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Weffc++")
```