# Cmake - select different c++ standard for different sources

Tags: c++, cmake

As the title suggest, I'd like to use cmake to build a project, and depending on the source file, enforcing a different c++ standard.

The reason is : I am working on a library and would like to make it c++03 compliant for compatibility, but would like to use Google test suite which requires c++11.

So the unit tests would be compiled with c++11, but I'd like my library to fail at compilation if there is reference to a c++11 only feature.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: It has a seance for different targets, but not for each source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So just do that - ompile your library with one standard, and your tests with the other. Nowadays, https://stackoverflow.com/a/61281312/9072753 method should be preferred.

```
add_library(mylib lib1.cpp)
set_target_properties(mylib
    PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 03
    CXX_EXTENSIONS off
    )

add_executable(mytest main.cpp)
set_target_properties(mytest
    PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 11
    CXX_EXTENSIONS off
    )
target_link_libraries(mytest PRIVATE mylib)
add_test(NAME mytest COMMAND mytest)
```

Comment: I'm quite new to cmake. I did not know about the concept of library. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, if they are used by different targets, using  [add_targrt_compile_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html) , as follows.

Assuming you want to use `c++03` with the lib and `c++11` with the exec, you may use something like what follows

```
add_executable(exec1 main.cpp)
add_library(lib1 STATIC lib1.cpp)
target_compile_options(lib1 PRIVATE -std=c++03)
target_compile_options(exec1 PRIVATE  -std=c++11)
```