# How to pass a vector to another vector push back? (without creating a extra variable to pass)

Tags: c++, stl, vector, multidimensional-array

Well I am questioning myself if there is a way to pass a vector directly in a parameter, with that I mean, like this:

```
int xPOS = 5, yPOS = 6, zPOS = 2;
//^this is actually a struct but 
//I simplified the code to this

std::vector <std::vector<int>>  NodePoints;
NodePoints.push_back(
    std::vector<int> {xPOS,yPOS,zPOS}
);
```

This code ofcourse gives an error; typename not allowed, and expected a ')'

I would have used a struct, but I have to pass the data to a Abstract Virtual Machine where I need to access the node positions as `Array[index][index]` like:

```
public GPS_WhenRouteIsCalculated(...)
{
    for(new i = 0; i < amount_of_nodes; ++i)
    {
        printf("Point(%d)=NodeID(%d), Position(X;Y;Z):{%f;%f;%f}",i,node_id_array[i],NodePosition[i][0],NodePosition[i][1],NodePosition[i][2]); 
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Ofcourse I could do it like this:

```
std::vector <std::vector<int>>  NodePoints;//global
std::vector<int> x;//local
x.push_back(xPOS);
x.push_back(yPOS);
x.push_back(zPOS);
NodePoints.push_back(x);
```

or this:

```
std::vector <std::vector<int>>  NodePoints;//global
std::vector<int> x;//global
x.push_back(xPOS);
x.push_back(yPOS);
x.push_back(zPOS);
NodePoints.push_back(x);
x.clear()
```

but then I'm wondering which of the two would be faster/more efficient/better?
Or is there a way to get my initial code working (first snippet)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use C++11, or something from boost for this (also you can use simple `v.push_back({1,2,3})`, vector will be constructed from initializer_list).

http://liveworkspace.org/code/m4kRJ$0

You can use boost::assign as well, if you have no C++11.

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>

using namespace boost::assign;

int main()
{
   std::vector<std::vector<int>> v;
   v.push_back(list_of(1)(2)(3));
}
```

http://liveworkspace.org/code/m4kRJ$5

and of course you can use old variant

```
int ptr[1,2,3];
v.push_back(std::vector<int>(ptr, ptr + sizeof(ptr) / sizeof(*ptr));
```

Comment: visual studio 2012 hates me . v.push_back({0,1,2}); won't compile -.-'

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to either Boost or C++11 then you could consider quite a simple solution based around a class. By wrapping a vector to store your three points within a class with some simple access controls, you can create the flexibility you need. First create the class:

```
class NodePoint
{
public:
    NodePoint( int a, int b, int c )
    {
        dim_.push_back( a );
        dim_.push_back( b );
        dim_.push_back( c );
    }

    int& operator[]( size_t i ){ return dim_[i]; }

private:
    vector<int> dim_;
};
```

The important thing here is to encapsulate the vector as an aggregate of the object. The `NodePoint` can only be initialised by providing the three points. I've also provided `operator[]` to allow indexed access to the object. It can be used as follows:

```
NodePoint a(5, 6, 2);
cout << a[0] << " " << a[1] << " " << a[2] << endl;
```

Which prints:

```
5 6 2
```

Note that this will of course throw if an attempt is made to access an out of bounds index point but that's still better than a fixed array which would most likely seg fault. I don't see this as a perfect solution but it should get you reasonably safely to where you want to be.

Answer (score 1):

If your main goal is to avoid unnecessary copies of `vector<>` then here how you should deal with it.

## C++03

Insert an empty vector into the nested vector (e.g. `Nodepoints`) and then use `std::swap()` or `std::vector::swap()` upon it.

```
NodePoints.push_back(std::vector<int>());  // add an empty vector
std::swap(x, NodePoints.back()); // swaps contents of `x` and last element of `NodePoints`
```

So after the `swap()`, the contents of `x` will be transferred to `NodePoints.back()` without any copying.

## C++11

Use `std::move()` to avoid extra copies

```
NodePoints.push_back(std::move(x));  // #include<utility>
```

Here is the [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413470/what-is-stdmove) of `std::move` and here is an [example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move).

Both of the above solutions have somewhat similar effect.