# Why move on const objects work?

Tags: c++, c++11, move, move-semantics

I have a simple code :

```
const std::vector<int> data = {1,2,3};
std::vector<int> data_moved=std::move(data);
for(auto& i:data)
    cout<<i;//output is 123
```

It compiles without any errors or warning !!

and It seems the `data`  still has the values in it !

moving a const value doesn't seems correct because we can not modify const objects So how does that code compiles ?!

Comment: Which compiler? What command-line flags? Come on.

Comment: Because const&& can also bind to const&. This is valid behavior.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413470/what-is-stdmove

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit https://ideone.com/WIk6Dx

Comment: @omid: No, I mean, your question should include details on the compiler you're using and how you're using it. Otherwise it is not a complete testcase.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**You're *not* moving anything.**

`std::move` is really poorly named: it doesn't *force* a move; it just returns an rvalue. It's up to the compiler to decide which constructor of `std::vector<int>` to invoke, and *that*'s what determines whether you get a move.

If the container can't be moved because the target's move constructor isn't a match, then the copy constructor will be used instead, through basic overload rules.

```
#include <iostream>

struct T
{
    T() = default;
    T(const T&) { std::cout << "copy ctor\n"; }
    T(T&&)      { std::cout << "move ctor\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    T a;
    T b = std::move(a);   // "move ctor"

    const T c;
    T d = std::move(c);   // "copy ctor" - `const T&&` only matches copy ctor



    // (shut up GCC)
    (void) b;
    (void) d;
}
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3ae744ed52ad066))

It's designed this way (`const T&&` being able to bind to `const T&`) at least in part because moving is intended to be best-effort, exactly so that you *don't* have to fight with compiler errors in cases like this.

Comment: He could also disable copying by wrapping the vector into another class called `MyVector`, for instance implement the same constructors that `vector` defines, make `operator=` private and then try to do the same thing and get a compile error.

Comment: @staticx: Which would be ridiculous.

Comment: Yes, but at least it would demonstrate that copying is occuring and not moving, or rather move semantics

Comment: Tnx I get it .. I think It's better to delete const&& ctor ..  T(const T&&)=delete;