# lvalue vs rvalue dubious

Tags: c++, c++11, move, lvalue, rvalue

The following code run fine but, for what I understand, it shouldn't

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Data
{
  explicit Data():value(1){}
  int value;
};

struct Foo
{
  explicit Foo(Data& data):data_(data){}

  inline void print() const
  {
    std::cout<<data_.value<<std::endl;
  }
  Data& data_;
};

void addEntry(std::vector<Foo>& vec)
{
  Data data;
  Foo foo(data);
  vec.push_back(foo);
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<Foo> vec;
  addEntry(vec);
  vec[0].print();
}
```

The function `addEnty` create an instance of `Data` called `data`. Then creates an instance of `Foo`, called `foo`, which stores a reference to `data`. This istance is then copyed inside the vector `vec`. Therefore, when the function end, `vec[0]` should contain a dangling reference since `data` is destroyed. Am I right? So I would expect to obtain some garbage calling the method `print()`. Is it only by chance that I obtain the right value 1 or am I missing something?

To make it correct, I would move data in order to avoid the dangling reference. So I would modify the constructor with

```
explicit Foo(Data&& data):data_(data){}
```

and the function with

```
Foo foo(std::move(data));
```

In this way `foo`, and consequently its copy inside `vec[0]`, contains the instance `data` instead of a reference to it. Am I right? Is it the correct solution? In this way, `Foo::data_` needs to be of type `Data` or of type `Data&`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes Foo will hold a dangling reference. Foo class should hold Data not Data& or Data&&.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Data
{
  explicit Data():value(1){}
  int value;
};

struct Foo
{
  // this is needed if you want to pass lvalue
  Foo(const Data& data):data_(data) 
  {}
  // for rvalue
  Foo(Data&& data):data_(std::move(data))
  {}

  void print() const
  {
    std::cout<<data_.value<<std::endl;
  }

  Data data_;
};

void addEntry(std::vector<Foo>& vec)
{
  vec.emplace_back(Foo(Data())); 

  // or

  Data data;
  // do somth with data
  vec.emplace_back(Foo(std::move(data)));        

  // or

  Data data;
  // do somth with data
  Foo foo {std::move(data)};
  // do somth with foo, but
  // do not use data here!!!
  vec.push_back(std::move(foo));        
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<Foo> vec;
  addEntry(vec);
  vec[0].print();
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to call `std::move` in the inizialization list of constructor `Foo(Data&&)` if you already need to call std::move when passing `data` to construct the object?

Comment: Because std::move doesn't move anything anywhere and just converts lvalue to rvalue and even when parameter in move constructor is declared  as `Data&&`, expression `data` is lvalue and needs to be converted to rvalue to call a move constructor of `Data` class

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413470/what-is-stdmove-and-when-should-it-be-used] Take a look here.

Comment: Yes I know that it only convert lvalues to rvalues. But when I call `Foo (std::move(data))` I convert it to an rvalue therefore I don't need `data_(std::move(data))` in the initialization list. When do I need this conversion? It seems to me that it is never used in your code. It is only to understand better these rvalues :)

Answer (score 2):

As you suggest, your sample code has undefined behaviour due to the dangling reference. The behaviour you see is just by chance.

A function taking an rvalue reference says "I'm going to steal data from whatever you pass in". Having a constructor take such a reference is fine so long as those are your semantics, but it doesn't seem like this is the case for your example.

A possibility would be to take the argument by-value, then move this into the member variable:

```
struct Foo
{
  explicit Foo(Data data):data_(std::move(data)){}
  Data data_;
};
```

This way, client code can either pass an lvalue (1 copy, 1 move) or an rvalue (2 moves). It's convenient to have only a single constructor to maintain, but this could be inefficient if `Data` is expensive to move.

Other possibilities would be having a single constructor taking a forwarding reference, or maintaining one overload for rvalues and one for lvalues.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, this is working by chance, this actually falls into Undefined Behavior.
Field should be `Data` type in `Foo` to avoid dangling reference.
You could rewrite this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Data
{
  explicit Data():value(1){}
  int value;
};

struct Foo
{
  explicit Foo(Data&& data):data_(std::move(data)){}

  inline void print() const
  {
    std::cout<<data_.value<<std::endl;
  }
  Data data_;
};

void addEntry(std::vector<Foo>& vec)
{
  vec.emplace_back(Foo(Data()));
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<Foo> vec;
  addEntry(vec);
  vec[0].print();
}
```