# std::move() and xvalue in C++

Tags: c++, xvalue, stdmove

Can someone give me an "acyclic" definition/explanation of xvalue and std::move() behaviour?

I looked on cppreference page, and it says "std::move() produces an xvalue". (Ok)

Then I looked for "xvalue"'s definition and the first thing it says is it's a function call or overloaded operator expression, such as "std:move". (???)

Comment: _"an xvalue is a glvalue that denotes an object or bit-field whose resources can be reused;"_ source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category

Comment: It uses `std::move` as an example of something that can produce an xvalue. It isn't saying that the definition of an xvalue is what `std::move` returns.

Comment: This has got to be a dupe; this has been discussed to death here.

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413470/what-is-stdmove-and-when-should-it-be-used

Answer (score 3):

`std::move()` converts an expression from being an *lvalue* or *rvalue* to being an *xvalue*.

An *lvalue* is an object occupies some location in memory while an *rvalue* occupies memory temporarily.

```
int main() {  
   int x = 3 + 4;  
   std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

In the example above, the `x` is an *lvalue* and the `3 + 4` is an *rvalue*. Now see the `x` is not temporary while `3 + 4` expression is a temporary value.

Now consider that you do this: `int y = x;`. You have two copies of that `x` in the memory right?

Check the example below:

```
swap(int &a, int &b) {
    int tmp = a;   // Two copies of a; one of them is tmp
    a = b;      // Two copies of b; one of them is a
    b = tmp;    // Two copies of tmp; one of them is b
}
```

Check the below example using `std::move()`:

```
swap(int &a, int &b) {
    int tmp = std::move(a); // tmp is an xvalue
    a = std::move(b);   
    b = std::move(tmp);
}
```

You don't copy; you move them somewhere instead. Actually, you transfer the content of it for some time. They are going to be destroyed soon. They are now `xvalue`s :)

Comment: In the second version of swap, tmp is an lvalue. The rhs of each of those three statements is an xvalue produced from an lvalue by std::move.

Answer (score 1):

There is no cyclic definition in [that sentence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category).

> The following expressions are xvalue expressions:
>
> a function call or an overloaded operator expression, whose return type is rvalue reference to object, such as std::move(x);
>
> ...

Here `std::move` is **merely** an example, the essence is "whose return type is rvalue reference". Since a function returning rvalue reference is not very usual, while `std::move` is aimed to do so, thus it serves a good example. This is the signature of `std::move`:

```
template< class T >
constexpr typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& move( T&& t ) noexcept;
```

whose return value must be an rvalue reference.