# Implicitly-declared move assignment operator

Tags: c++11, move

I'm having trouble getting my head around this simple rule from cpp reference;

> If no user-defined move assignment operators are provided for a class
>   type (struct, class, or union), and all of the following is true:
>
> there are no user-declared copy constructors;
>
> there are no user-declared move constructors;
>
> there are no user-declared copy assignment operators;
>
> there are no user-declared destructors;
>
> the implicitly-declared move assignment operator would not be defined 
>   as deleted, (until C++14)
>
> THEN the compiler **WILL**  declare a move assignment operator as an inline public member of its class with the  signature T& T::operator=(T&&).

With this in mind, consider

```
struct bar
{

   bar(int i) : _i(i) {};
   bar (const bar& other) { };
   bar (bar& other) { };

   int _i;
};
```

Followed by this, say;

```
   bar b2(2);
   bar b3(3);
   cout << "b3._i " << b3._i << endl << endl;
   b3 = std::move(b2);
   cout << "b3._i " << b3._i << endl;
```

The output we get is;

b3._i 3

b3._i 2

So here we have a move happening;

```
b3 = std::move(b2);
```

I didn't define that move assignment operator, so its been implicitly defined for me by the compiler. However I **have** broken the conditions laid down, I HAVE a user defined copy ctor.... however there is still a move happening by the compiler generated one. I'm clearly misinterpreting the text, can anybody be so good as to enlighten me?

Thanks and have a nice day.

G

Comment: It is often a misconception to think that `std::move` moves the object. Refer to [What is std::move, and when should it be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413470/what-is-stdmove-and-when-should-it-be-used).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So here we have a move happening;
>
> ```
> b3 = std::move(b2);
> ```

Nope, this is a copy. `std::move(b2)` simply casts `b2` to `bar&&`. `bar&&` then binds to `const bar&` in the implicitly-generated copy-assignment operator.

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rDxQRip21coHkpm7)