# Why does make_shared destroy rvalue-references?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, move-semantics

I'm trying to understand how I should use smart pointers efficiently, and I got curious about how they work together with rvalue references. How come `std::make_shared` (and presumably `make_unique` as well) uses copy semantics and not move semantics?

Here's a gtest test that showcases what I'm trying to say

```cpp
#include <memory>
int dtor_calls = 0;
struct MoveSemanticsTest1 {
    int data;
    ~MoveSemanticsTest1() { dtor_calls++; }
};

void reset_move_dtor_calls() {
    dtor_calls = 0;
}

TEST(MoveSemanticsSanityTest1, SanityTests) {
    reset_move_dtor_calls();
    {
        MoveSemanticsTest1 a = MoveSemanticsTest1();
    }
    EXPECT_EQ(1, dtor_calls); // <-- This passes, makes sense
    reset_move_dtor_calls();
    {
        MoveSemanticsTest1 b = {3};
        auto a = std::make_shared<MoveSemanticsTest1>(std::move(b));
    }
    EXPECT_EQ(1, dtor_calls); // <-- This fails, why?
    reset_move_dtor_calls();
    {
        MoveSemanticsTest1 b = {3};
        auto a = std::make_shared<MoveSemanticsTest1>(b);
    }
    EXPECT_EQ(2, dtor_calls); // <-- This passes, makes sense because of the copying
}
```

The second `EXPECT_EQ` fails, which hints to the moved `b` resource doesn't actually move the resource.

Comment: std::move just make a cast to rvalue reference and move nothing. There targeted variable will be left in valid state, so the destructor will be called

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11148420/4658169

Comment: Where is your move constructor/move assignment operator?  And note that `std::move` is *nothing but a cast* to rvalue reference. It doesn't do *anything* on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
reset_move_dtor_calls();
{
    MoveSemanticsTest1 b = {3};  //1 
    auto a = std::make_shared<MoveSemanticsTest1>(std::move(b));  //2
    //3
    //4
}
```

In 1) you create a `MoveSemanticsTest1`.

In 2) you create a `MoveSemanticsTest1` by move construction an give it to a `shared_ptr`. `b` is in a "moved from" state, but still here.

In 3) you destroy the `shared_ptr` => it destroy its  `MoveSemanticsTest1`

In 4) you destroy the  `MoveSemanticsTest1` `b`.

I count 2 call to the destructor.