# Correct way to return istream from function

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, istream

I am testing speed of various data reading techniques from istream so I created a function to repeatedly create istream from file so next method that is tested can consume that istream.

```
using std::istream;
using std::string;

istream* getStreamFrom(string filepath)
{
    std::filebuf init_buffer;
    if (init_buffer.open(filepath, std::ios::in))
    {
        std::istream inputStream(&init_buffer);
        init_buffer.close();
        return &inputStream;
    }

    // file not found
    istream inputStream(0);
    return &inputStream;
}
```

And then I pass the istream to tested method like this:

```
istream* data = getStreamFrom(FILEPATH);
someMethod(*data);
```

But in `someMethod` I get access violation when reading from istream:

```
void someMethod(istream& input)
{
    string line;
    while (std::getline(input, line))    // code failes here
        // do something
}
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix this? It does not matter if file is found or not, it happens in both cases.

Comment: `inputStream` is destroyed when `getStreamFrom` ends. So the pointer to it is then invalid.

Comment: You are returning the address of a local variable - which causes *undefined behaviour*! See, for example, here: [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope).

Comment: Even if you resolve the problem of the `istream` ceasing to exist as the function returns, you need to take care of the `file_buf` since it ALSO ceases to exist as the function returns - independently of the `istream`.  Passing the address of the buffer to the `istream` does not change that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to return a local stream from a function then you need to both dynamically allocate the stream and its buffer. As the comments and the answer have explained you are returning pointers to local variables that will be destroyed after the function exits. The standard stream classes `std::istream` and `std::ostream` are not movable, so your only option is to create the objects on the heap. Both the stream and the buffer can be  wrapped in a smart pointer to avoid manual memory mangement.

```
std::unique_ptr<std::istream> getStreamFrom(std::string filepath) {
  auto init_buf = std::make_unique<std::filebuf>();
  return std::make_unique<std::istream>(
    init_buf->open(filepath, std::ios_base::in)
      ? init_buf.release()->close()
      : nullptr
  );
}
```

BTW an `std::istream` initialized with a `std::filebuf` is a `std::fstream`. You could also return a pointer to that as well:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::ifstream> getStreamFrom(std::string filepath) {
  auto stream = std::make_unique<std::ifstream>(filepath);
  stream->close();
  return std::unique_ptr<std::ifstream>( *stream ? std::move(stream) : nullptr );
}
```

With optional in C++17:

```
std::optional<std::ifstream> getStreamFrom(std::string filepath) {
  std::ifstream stream(filepath);
  stream.close();
  return stream ? std::optional(std::move(stream)) : std::nullopt;
}
```

Comment: Why are you closing the stream before returning?  All that achieves is forcing the caller to re-open the stream.

Comment: @Peter Because that's what the OP did. I was trying to replicate his code as much as possible.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Yeah. I found out that whatever you do, if you close buffer before returning the istream, you will get another violation. So solution is to either make completely new wrapper around istream-buffer or create istream in main code without function call.

Comment: @sanitizedUser What violation are you talking about?

Comment: @0x499602D2 I already deleted the code but it said something about reading closed buffer is not a good idea.

Comment: @sanitizedUser Why are you closing the buffer anyway? Why not keep it open?

Comment: @0x499602D2 I don't how to close the buffer after istream is returned from function and buffer exits scope. I heard closing buffer is good practice.

Comment: @sanitizedUser Well, first off you shouldn't need to initialize an `std::istream` with a `std::filebuf`. In that situation you *would* have to close the buffer manually if you wanted to close the file. But there's a dedicated class for files called `std::fstream` (and `std::ifstream` and `std::ostream`) that will close the buffer automatically when the file goes out of scope. Simply construct a `std::ifstream file(filename)` and that's really all you need.

Answer (score 0):

`inputStream` is going our of scope once your function exits. Accessing the `std::istream*` outside the function will result in undefined behavior.

Probably the best way to do this is with a `std::shared_ptr`. Something like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::istream> getStreamFrom(string filepath)
{
    std::filebuf init_buffer;
    if (init_buffer.open(filepath, std::ios::in))
    {
        std::shared_ptr<std::istream> inputStream = std::make_shared<std::istream>(&init_buffer);
        init_buffer.close();
        return inputStream;
    }

    // file not found
    std::shared_ptr<std::istream> inputStream = std::make_shared<istream>(nullptr);
    return inputStream;
}
```

Of course, `init_buffer` is also about to go out of scope. Not really sure what the right thing to do here is, as [passing it directly into `std::istream` won't delete the buffer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/~basic_istream). I don't know what the right way to do it would be here, as you aren't making your own `std::istream`, so the suggested solution won't work for you. So you're kind of on your own for that. But you have been warned.

One thing you could do is instead [`std::move()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) it. Here is some [more information on `std::move()`ing things](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3413470/10957435).