# Using std::move over ofstream

Tags: c++, mutex, ofstream, stdmove

While trying some mutex-locked print function, I got an idea like this:

```
class MyWriteStream
{
public:
    MyWriteStream(std::ostream &stream) : stream_(std::move(stream)) {}

    void write(const char *str, const size_t size)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        stream_.write(str, size);
    }

    friend MyWriteStream & operator << (MyWriteStream &out, const char *c);

private:
    std::ostream &&stream_;
    std::mutex mutex_;
};

MyWriteStream & operator << (MyWriteStream &out, const char *c)
{
    out.write(c, strlen(c) * sizeof(char));
    return out;
}
```

And while calling, I did something like this:

```
MyWriteStream stream(std::cout);
auto blah = [&stream](const char *s) {
    stream << s << "\n";
};
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
for (auto i = 0; i<10; ++i) {
    std::string str = "blah : " + std::to_string(i);
    threads.push_back(std::thread(blah, str.c_str()));
}
for (auto &thread : threads) {
    thread.join();
}

std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;  // Still Works
```

It appears I didn't manage to move `std::cout`, as next line still works. What has happened? Could `std::move` also bind reference? Also, if I were to make it into usable class, was this a bad idea?
 [Edit] It does look like bad idea, as there is issue with synchronization. I'm trying to understand same. Any hints are most welcome. I guess, I need to study r-value references in more depth.

Comment: `std::move` doesn't move.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27026280.

Comment: I tracked it down to resource management issue. Problem was the caller. Pointer, str.c_str() was destroyed long before thread was created. Assuming same stack space for locals, this was hit or miss. I changed it to RAII std::string, and it appears to work!