# Move operator not passing the ownership

Tags: c++, move-semantics

The program

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct abhi{
int a=2;
int b=1;
~abhi(){cout<<"destroyed"<<endl;}
};

void  su(int a, int b, abhi&& ptr){
cout<<"yes"<<endl;
}

int main(){
abhi ptr;
su(1,2,move(ptr));
cout<<"after"<<endl;
}
```

The Output

```
yes
after
destroyed
```

Shouldnt the destructor be called inside the `su` function as I using `move` to pass the `ptr`.
I have used `move` operator with `unique_ptr` and it used to pass the ownership completely, so I am getting different result with plain `pointer`.

Comment: You are passing the object ptr by reference (rvalue reference). So neither destructor is called because the object ptr is not a temporary object.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow no I m passing rvalue reference so either my calling function shoud be a constant, in  this case `{}` or using `move` to pass my `ptr` as rvalue

Comment: Moving a `unique_ptr` doesn't call its destructor. Whatever you were observing wasn't that.

Comment: @chris I m not telling move will call the destructure of a `unique_ptr` but it will pass the ownership to the caller function and when that called function is finished then the destructor of that moved unique_ptr will be called, but in this case I m not seeing this.Is it due to fact that I using stack allocated variable `ptr` and not a pointer?

Comment: I'm not understanding why you expect moving your own type to call its destructor then. What does it mean for ownership of your type to transfer? And Vlad's point still applies: `std::move` doesn't immediately move, it just casts to an rvalue reference, so the object really is being passed by reference here. (Move operations are also disabled entirely for your type because you spelled out its destructor.)

Comment: @chris okay I think I got this, thanks :)

Comment: 1. Rule of Five. 2. Std::move doesn't move, it is just a way to case a value to an 'rvalue-ref', at one point it was proposed to be called 'rvalue_cast`. 3. Learn about scope.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is std::move(), and when should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413470/what-is-stdmove-and-when-should-it-be-used)