# std::move with polymorphic move assignment operator and memory safety

Tags: c++, inheritance, memory, polymorphism, move-semantics

I was wondering if the following code was safe, considering the child object is implicitly converted to type `Parent` and then moved from memory. In other words, when passing `other` to `Parent::operator=(Parent&&)` from `Child::operator(Child&&)`, is the entire object "moved" with the parent call, or just the underlying `Parent` object?

```cpp
class Parent
{
public:
     // Constructors

     Parent& operator=(Parent&& other) noexcept
     {
          if (this == &other)
               return *this;

          str1_ = std::move(other.str1_);
          str2_ = std::move(other.str2_);
          return *this;
     }

protected:
     std::string str1_, str2_;
};

class Child : public Parent
{
public:
     // Constructors

     Child& operator=(Child&& other) noexcept
     {
          if (this == &other)
               return *this;

          // Are the following 2 lines memory safe?
          Parent::operator=(std::move(other));
          str3_ = std::move(other.str3_);

          return *this;
     }

private:
     std::string str3_;
};
```

Comment: *"is the entire object "moved..."      "* Nothing is actually "moved". See [`std::move()` doesn't actually move anything.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27026280/12002570)

Comment: @AnoopRana Could you explain why?

Comment: Refer to [`std::move()` doesn't actually move anything.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27026280/12002570)

Comment: Re: "the child object is implicitly cast" -- the child object is implicitly **converted**. A cast is never implicit; it's something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Comment: @AnoopRana From my understanding of that article, the underlying char* of each string is still reassigned, making parts or all (which is where my question lies) of `other` unusable. Is that a correct interpretation at all?

Comment: @PeteBecker Thank you for the clarifyication. I will fix the question's wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is safe. You are just passing a reference to the base-class subobject to the base assignment operator. `std::move` doesn't move anything. It just makes an xvalue out of an lvalue, so that a rvalue reference may bind to it. The binding here is to a subobject because `Parent` is a base class type of `Child`.

In fact you are exactly replicating the behavior that a defaulted move assignment operator would have (except that it wouldn't check for self-assignment, which is pointless if you are only forwarding to other assignment operators), which begs the question why you are defining it at all? Just follow the rule-of-zero and don't declare a move assignment operator.

This goes for both `Parent`'s and `Child`'s move assignment operator.

Comment: This is a simplified version of a more involved class I'm writing. I apologize if it was oversimplified in this case, but thank you for your answer.