# Does C++ allows move semantics on int[]?

Tags: c++, arrays, move

I want to do something like this:

```
    int data[4] = {1,2,3,4};
    int otherData[4];
    otherData = std::move(data);
```

compiler says invalid array assignment, so how can I transfer values from data to otherData

Comment: No, you cannot move one C style array into another.

Comment: C-array are not moveable/copyable. [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is a good alternative.

Comment: Why don't you use `memcpy`?

Comment: BTW, moving `int` would be same as a copy.

Comment: If you only have a few elements in the array and it's a fixed size, use `std::array` as @Jarod42 suggested. It'll then _copy_ the elements in the array (even if you `std::move()`) since fundamental types can only be copied. If you have many elements in the array that you want to move around, using a `std::vector<int>` would perhaps be beneficial.

Comment: @DemonKing See here [`std::move` doesn't actually move anything](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27026280/12002570)

Comment: `std::array<int, 4> data{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }; std::array<int, 4> otherData; otherData = data;`