# Having trouble understanding C++ constructors and destructors and move/copy semantics

Tags: c++, move, destructor, copy-constructor

I have the following program where I test the order of constructor and destructor calls and I was surprised by the output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>


class Doctor {
    public:
    Doctor(){
        std::cout << "Doctor Creation\n";
    }

    ~Doctor(){
        std::cout << "Doctor DeCreation\n";
    }
};


class Nurse{
    public:
    int op = 0;
    Nurse(){
        std::cout << "Nurse Creation\n";
    }

    ~Nurse(){
        std::cout << "Nurse " <<  op << " DeCreation\n";
    }
};

class Hospital{
    private:
        Doctor doc;
        Nurse nurse;
    public:
    Hospital(){
        std::cout << "Hospital Creation\n";
    }
    ~Hospital(){
        std::cout << "Hospital DeCreation\n";
    }

    void operate(){
        std::cout << "Hospital Operation\n";
        nurse.op++;
        std::cout << &this->nurse << " " << nurse.op << "\n";
        reset_hospital();
        std::cout << &this->nurse << " " << nurse.op << "\n";
    }

    void reset_hospital(){
        std::cout << &this->nurse << " " << nurse.op << "\n";
        nurse = std::move(Nurse());
        doc = std::move(Doctor());
    }
};

int main(){
    Hospital hospital;
    hospital.operate();
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/bf8KbqsTK

The output is:

```
Doctor Creation
Nurse Creation
Hospital Creation
Hospital Operation
0x7fff2316866c 1
0x7fff2316866c 1
Nurse Creation
Nurse 0 DeCreation
Doctor Creation
Doctor DeCreation
0x7fff2316866c 0
Hospital DeCreation
Nurse 0 DeCreation
Doctor DeCreation
```

Shouldn't it be `Nurse 1 DeCreation` on the std::move operation? The current object is destroyed and replaced by the new one? Or for some reason, is it copying instead of moving?

I'm so confused.

Comment: C++ should be learnt using a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead of by trial and error. In particular, this is explained in any beginner c++ book. It is not clear what you're confused about. Also, refer to [std::move doesn't actually move anything](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27026280/12002570).

Comment: In `nurse = std::move(Nurse());`the `std::move` does nothing. `Nurse()` is already an rvalue

Comment: There's no reason why copying (assignment) a new nurse object to an old one via assignment would call the dtor. It just copies the guts (ie:op) of the new one to the old one.

Comment: @doug I believe OP expects the copy assignment to actually be a move assignment, and expects that move assignment to perform a swap.

Comment: @JohnFilleau Yeah, I think you're right. It doesn't have a move assigment and if it did it wouldn't normally swap op. I suppose he could write a move assignment with a swap. That should do what he expects.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

`Nurse 0 DeCreation` is shown instead of `Nurse 1 DeCreation` because:

1. `Nurse` has no move assignment operator (see explanation below),
2. `Nurse` has a copy assignment operator that is used, and
3. If `Nurse` had an implicitly-defined move assignment operator, it would be trivial, and the members would be acted on as if by `std::memmove`, which would not swap the underlying `op` member

Move semantics do not guarantee that a swap will occur. In the case of trivially movable member variables, assignment is much more efficient than swapping. Move semantics don't necessarily guarantee that the "moved-from" object will be the same as the previous state of the "moved-to" object. Move semantics only (should) guarantee that the moved-from object is in a valid  state. It can be unspecified.

### Why no move assignment operator?

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment

> If no user-defined move assignment operators are provided for a class type (struct, class, or union), and all of the following is true:
>
> - there are no user-declared copy constructors;
> - there are no user-declared move constructors;
> - there are no user-declared copy assignment operators;
> - there is no user-declared destructor,
>
> then the compiler will declare a move assignment operator as an inline public member of its class with the signature T& T::operator=(T&&).

*`Nurse` has a user-declared destructor, and therefore has no implicitly declared move assignment operator*

`Nurse` *does* have an implicitly defined copy assignment operator, and its members are copied. The first-destroyed `Nurse` object has `op = 0`, so you see `Nurse 0 DecCreation`.

### What if it did have a move assignment operator?

If `~Nurse()` was not user provided, then `Nurse` would have an implicitly declared move assignment operator. It would also be a *trivial* move assignment operator, which only guarantees the members are assigned as if using `std::memmove`. I.e., byte-wise copied.