# CPP, WinAPI - WM_CREATE proper way to get CREATESTRUCT* from lParam

Tags: c++, winapi, pointers, casting, struct

A certain tutorial for the Win32 API uses this line to transform the `lParam` argument from a `WM_CREATE` message in the main window procedure into a `CREATESTRUCT*`:

```
reinterpret_cast<CREATESTRUCT*>(lParam)  // Method 1
```

I've read elsewhere that `reinterpret_cast` is dangerous and results in undefined behavior, lightning bolts, and whatnot.

---

I've used a more conventional cast which the compiler doesn't complain about:

```
(CREATESTRUCT*) lParam // Method 2
```

Is there a reason the author of the tutorial did it their way?

And, I'm sure there's a better way than mine?

Comment: To know which cast use, you shoud check out [this wiki post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used), I always read it whenerver I have doubt on cast. In your case, I think a static_cast is this cleanest answer, since the "C cast can devolve into a reinterpret cast" (sic)

Comment: @georgesl, you cannot static-cast an integer to a pointer.

Comment: hmm, where is the int ? is it LPARAM ?

Comment: @georgesl, yes, `LPARAM` is an integer.

Comment: @georgesl - thanks, actually that was one of the sparks that triggered the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"(CREATESTRUCT*) lParam"** form is called a c-style cast. When this is used the compiler would try all possible ways to convert the expression (lParam - here) to the type (CREATESTRUCT* - here).

Let me explain all possible ways of casting,

1. Casting from "const/volatile T" to T - in C++ a programmer picks this way using **const_cast**
2. Casting from "T" to "R" where T and R are related. E.g. like int/char, Car/Vehicle etc. - in C++ a programmer picks this way of casting using **static_cast**.
3. Casting from "T" to "R" where T and R are related, along with runtime check. E.g. T = Vehicle and R = Car, conversion from T type object to R type object is valid statically but in reality (at runtime) compiler (through hidden code) has to check if the object being type-casted is indeed a Car or a derivative of Car. - in C++ a programmer picks this way of casting using **dynamic_cast**.
4. Casting from "U" to "V" where U and V are unrelated. - in C++ a programmer picks this way of casting using **reinterpret_cast**.

If a c-style cast is used in C++ by a programmer, he is telling the compiler to try all possible ways to convert/perceive an expression to/as a particular type.

The only reason c-style cast is dangerous is because the real intention of the programmer is not properly conveyed to the compiler and fellow programmers who would be reading the code. Sometimes a programmer may only have meant a static_cast and not reinterpret_cast but using a c-style cast would cause an error at run-time which could have been caught at compile time. Because compiler error would occur if the programmer uses static_cast on unrelated types.

And user defined cast operators affects some behaviors a bit more (esp. static_cast) but does not change the fundamentals.

Comment: Thanks @nanda. I'm a little torn who to accept but I'm going with your answer since it explains both sides of my question.

Answer (score 4):

Both constructs are equivalent in this particular case. There is no undefined behavior -- the C++ standard guarantees that reinterpret-casting a pointer to a sufficiently wide integer and back results in the same pointer.

You can safely assume that Windows created the `lParam` value from the original pointer as if by `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: Also, the `(CREATESTRUCT *)` syntax (aka the *C-style cast*) says "use a `reinterpret_cast` or a `static_cast`, whichever works", so functionally, they are the same, just with less error checking.

Comment: +1 OK thanks fellas, that's a great help. @SimonRichter - do you have a link for that?  Had a quick skim of CREATESTRUCT documentation but no dice.  If too much trouble no worries, just curious.

Comment: @Steve, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609163/what-is-the-difference-between-static-cast-and-c-style-casting).