# Casting between primitive type pointers

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, strict-aliasing

Is the following well-defined:

```
char* charPtr = new char[42];
int* intPtr = (int*)charPtr;

charPtr++;
intPtr = (int*) charPtr;
```

The `intPtr` isn't properly aligned (in at least one of the two cases). Is it illegal just having it there? Is it UB using it at any stage? How can you use it and how can't you?

Comment: Unaligned access would happen (on relevant processors) if you tried to use `intPtr` after this. So it would definitely not be acceptable. Although it may work on some processors - e.g. x86 will happily, if a little slower, read unaligned memory.

Comment: I think you can cast back, but can't use it after cast :) I'd have to check that though.

Comment: What do you mean by, "Can you cast it back?"

Comment: @JohnDibling removed that part (found out casting back is required to work).

Comment: @JohnDibling: He means "regardless of the validity of `intPtr`, can I at least cast `intPtr` to `char*` and re-obtain the original, valid pointer for suresies?"

Comment: @JohnDibling: And the answer is "only if `T1` and `T2` are object types and where the alignment requirements of `T2` are no stricter than those of `T1`, otherwise it's _unspecified_" (`[C++11: 5.2.10/7]`).

Comment: In `C++` better use `static_cast` instead of `C` style casting.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563045/when-c-style-cast-is-allowed

Comment: @Mysticial I am not sure which answer precisely you meant but I kind of agree with [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1609185/812912)

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev don't get too hung up on the cast itself, that's not the question here.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Except that `static_cast` isn't legal here.  He'd have to use `reinterpret_cast`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, of course: the pointer is guaranteed to be aligned in the
first case (by §5.3.4/10 and §3.7.4.1/2), and may be correctly
aligned in both cases.  (Obviously, if `sizeof(int) == 1`, but
even when this is not the case, an implementation doesn't
necessarily have alignment requirements.)

And to make things clear: your casts are all `reinterpret_cast`.

Beyond that, this is an interesting question, because as far as
I can tell, there is no difference in the two casts, as far as
the standard is concerned.  The results of the conversion are
unspecified (according to §5.2.10/7); you're not even guaranteed
that converting it back into a `char*` will result in the
original value.  (It obviously won't, for example, on machines
where `int*` is smaller than a `char*`.)

In practice, of course: the standard requires that the return
value of `new char[N]` be sufficiently aligned for any value
which may fit into it, so you are guaranteed to be able to do:

```
intPtr = new (charPtr) int;
```

Which has exactly the same effect as your cast, given that the
default constructor for `int` is a no-op.  (And assuming that
`sizeof(int) <= 42`.)  So it's hard to imagine an implementation
in which the first part fails.  You should be able to use the
`intPtr` just like any other legally obtained `intPtr`.  And the
idea that converting it back to a `char*` would somehow result
in a different value from the original `char*` seems
preposterous.

In the second part, all bets are off: you definitely can't
dereference the pointer (unless your implementation guarantees
otherwise), and it's also quite possible that converting it back
to `char*` results in something different.  (Imagine a word
addressed machine, for example, where converting a `char*` to an
`int*` rounds up.  Then converting back would result in
a `char*` which was `sizeof(int)` higher than the original.  Or
where an attempt to convert a misaligned pointer always resulted
in a null pointer.)

Answer (score 3):

In general, the result is unspecified (5.2.10p7) if the alignment requirements of `int` are greater than those of `char`, which they usually will be.  The result will be a valid value of the type `int *` so it can be e.g. printed as a pointer with `operator<<` or converted to `intptr_t`.

Because the result has an unspecified value, unless specified by the implementation it is undefined behaviour to indirect it and perform lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on the resulting `int` lvalue (except in unevaluated contexts).  Converting back to `char *` will not necessarily round-trip.

However, if the original `char *` was itself the result of a cast from `int *`, then the cast to `int *` counts as the second half of a round trip; in that case, the cast is defined.

In particular, in the case above where the `char *` was the result of a `new[]` expression, we are guaranteed (5.3.4p10) that the `char *` pointer is appropriately aligned for `int`, as long as `sizeof(int) <= 42`.  Because the `new[]` expression obtains its storage from an allocation function, 3.7.4.1p2 applies; the `void *` pointer *can be converted
to a pointer of any complete object type with a fundamental alignment requirement and then used to access the object [...]* which strongly implies, along with the note to 5.3.4p10, that the same holds for the `char *` pointer returned by the `new[]` expression.  In this case the `int *` is a pointer to an uninitialised `int` object, so performing lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on its indirection is undefined (3.8p6), but assigning to its indirection is fully defined.  The `int` object is *in the storage allocated* (3.7.4.1p2) so converting the `int *` back to `char *` will yield the original value per 1.8p6.  This does not hold for the incremented `char *` pointer as unless `sizeof(int) == 1` it is not the address of an `int` object.

Comment: The original `char*` was the result of `new char[42]`.