# typecast long pointer issue

Tags: c++, c

```
  char *sBuffer=new char[20];
    char * sStringStart = sBuffer;

    long * plMsgStart = (long *) sBuffer;// what is this line doing

    long i=500;

    *plMsgStart = i // what is this line doing
```

Is the last line assigning 500 in char array ? but when i print the array i get garbage values

Hey guys below is the actual code and i encountered it when i was converting code from c++ to c#, this below code is part from c++ function, now why below function gives garbage values ?

```
char *sBuffer=new char[20];
char * sStringStart = sBuffer;
BSTR bsMsgBody= SysAllocString(L"Helo");
sStringStart+=4;
long * plMsgStart = (long *) sBuffer;

long l=50;

*plMsgStart=l;

sprintf(sStringStart, "%S", bsMsgBody);

printf("%S",sBuffer);
```

Comment: assuming its not crazy, the first `sizeof(long)` characters are treated as a long variable and is set to 500. depends on the endianess how the data is stored. yeah it **looks** like garbage but going through it, you can see how '500' is stored

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a cast. It says "I know what I'm doing, I want to treat this `char*` as if it were a `long*`". Afterwards, it assigns `i` to the first element (equivalent to `plMsgStart[0] = i;`.

Depending on the size of `long`, you'll overwrite the first 4 or 8 elements in the `char` array. Printing it is still undefined behavior, because `sBuffer` wasn't null-terminated to start with.

If you did

```
 char *sBuffer=new char[20]();
```

and then attempt to print `sBuffer` (after the `long` overwrite), you'll see 4 (or 8) characters corresponding to the binary representation of `500`.

Visual

```
 char *sBuffer=new char[20];

 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

 long * plMsgStart = (long *) sBuffer;

 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 |       |       |       |       |       |
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

                 ^^^^^
    note this is still the same memory,
   but "seen through the eyes" of a long*


 *plMsgStart = 500;

 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 |  500  |       |       |       |       |
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

Comment: I think the whole thing is UB, because it's a violation of type-aliasing rules.  And there maybe an alignment issue as well...

Comment: I *think* so; it's accessing an object via a pointer to an incompatible type (I'm extrapolating slightly from the rules in C here, perhaps it's  different in C++).  As for alignment, that could certainly be a problem (depending on what your platform allows).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I think `new` returns a correctly-aligned pointer to word size. I'm not sure it isn't, but I doubt it.

Comment: Is that alignment guaranteed?

Comment: but why printf("%s",sBuffer); gives garbage values.

Comment: @kamal it's undefined behavior because `sBuffer` isn't initialized - it's not null terminated. Did you try the test I suggested?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth §5.3.4/10 and §3.7.4.1/2 - didn't check, taken from http://stackoverflow.com/a/14774681/673730

Comment: @kamal: Because `printf("%s",...)` expects an array of printable characters with a null terminator at the end. Instead, you're using an evil cast to give it the bytes that represent `(long)500`. As a string, that's garbage, so you'll get garbage (or other undefined behaviour) out.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Ah, that's interesting.  I had a brief look at those paragraphs, and it seems like the alignment is indeed not an issue (although I find the C++ standard pretty tough to parse...)

Answer (score 2):

This code creates a 20 byte long buffer called `sBuffer`, then stores a long with the value 500 in the first `n` bytes of the buffer, where `n` is the number of bytes required to store a `long` on your system.

```
long * plMsgStart = (long *) sBuffer;// what is this line doing
```

This line is the one that tells the compiler that you want `plMsgStart` to be the same memory block as `sBuffer`, but the block should be treated as if it stores `long`s.

Comment: but why printf("%s",sBuffer); gives garbage values

Comment: Because %s expects an array of bytes containing ASCII values followed by a byte with the value of 0. If you want to print out `500`, then you want `printf("%ld", plMsgStart[0]);`

Answer (score 2):

...I'm not sure how to make it much simpler, but I'll try:

```
char *sBuffer // sBuffer is a pointer to a character type

long * plMsgStart  // plMsgStart is a pointer to a long type

(long *) sBuffer;// this tells the compiler that I want my char pointer to be treated
                 // as a long pointer during this assignment.
```

This makes it such that `plMsgStart` is pointing at `sBuffer`.

```
*plMsgStart = i; // this is dereferencing the pointer, it says: 
                 // "at the current memory location" store the value i
```

So in effect, the memory pointed to by `sBuffer` is being set the value of `500`, if you try to access this as a long you *should* see 500; if you try to access `sBuffer` as a char (or char array) you're most likely going to get a garbage. This is a perfect reason *not* to [typecast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558837/what-exactly-is-a-type-cast-in-c-c#), because the compiler shouldn't complain about anything you did, but you just overflowed the first element of your character array (`char` takes values up to 255)

you stored 500 into that memory, that would be:

0000 0001 1111 0100<sub>2</sub> If you look at this in byte form:

[00000001] [11110100] ==> [0x1][-0x12] (signed)
                      
or
[00000001] [11110100] ==> [0x1][0xF4] (unsigned)

So when you try to print that "string" you're seeing garbage (or at best an 'O' if `char` is `unsigned` on your system).

Comment: since its an array, and that he casts it to type `long` the first `sizeof(long)` will hold 500?. and char should take -128 to 127?

Comment: @Koushik, you're right about the first part (at least on most systems).  About `char`, the standard doesn't define if plain `char` is signed or unsigned.  So, the "correct" range is `CHAR_MIN` to `CHAR_MAX`.

Comment: @Alok thanks for the correction. so 'char''s sign is implementation defined?

Comment: @Koushik - An array is just a bunch of contiguous bytes. The size of a `char` is 1 byte, the size of a `long` depends on your system, but 8 bytes is a safe bet. So technically, yes, you can store a `long` into a character array of size 20 and access it as a long. But this makes no sense... 20 bytes can only store 2 full `long`s..
WRT the values a char holds, the MAX a char can ever hold (regardless of sign) is 255, so I mentioned that number

Comment: @Mike i agree with that but your **sBuffer's first element is set the value of 500** is what i had in mind while commenting.

Comment: but why printf("%s",sBuffer); gives garbage values

Comment: @Koushik - OK, I see what you're saying. Yes, I worded it funny, but if you were to access `sBuffer` as a long (ie `printf("%ld",*plMsgStart);`) then you'd get 500 (taking up the first 8 of 20 reserved bytes). However if you try to access it as a char buffer as `sBuffer` was originally defined as, the first element is not going to be the expected 500 because that overflows a char type. Is I guess what I meant to say.

Comment: @kamal - because you overflowed the `char` type, so you're getting (I assume) non-printable characters.. alphanumeric at least.

Comment: +1 for detailed explanation. this and lucian grigore's answer should leave no doubts.