# Can pointers be of different sizes?

Tags: c++, pointers, language-lawyer

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14774681/673730) comes with an interesting statement - "on machines where `int*` is smaller than a `char*`". (let's exclude pointers to functions)

Is it possible for pointers to different types to have different sizes? Why would this be useful?

Comment: This may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12006854/why-the-size-of-a-pointer-to-a-function-is-different-from-the-size-of-a-pointer

Comment: @KirilKirov that is interesting (I guess I immediately excluded function pointers from my train of thought). Good info!

Comment: @KirilKirov I was lazy enough not to check your link, but it seems that after all, my answer is redundant -.-

Comment: If I'm not wrong, there are very specific platforms, where `char*` and `int*` have different sizes. It's been a while, since I read about this, but if I remember correctly - this is very rare and is more relevant for some embedded systems.

Comment: All answers mentioned the size is not guaranteed. But [`uintptr_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) is fixed size for all pointer types!?

Comment: As I said elsewhere `uintptr_t` is guaranteed to be "large enough to hold all pointer types", similar to `void *`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it's entirely possible. On some machines, a pointer to a byte contains two values: A pointer to the WORD address of the memory word containing the byte, and a "byte index" that gives the position of the byte within the word. E.g. on a 32-bit machine, the "byte index" is 0..3.

This would require more storage space than a "int *", which is just a pointer to the relevant word.

Comment: Indeed. One could even imagine some kind of weird machine where different data is stored in different memory banks entirely, each addressed in their own way.

Comment: Can you please name such machines, Mats?

Comment: @MartinVidner: I just invented one in my mind for you.

Comment: Alpha processors before EV56, as per my quick googling, doesn't support "byte addressing" - each memory read/write has to be an entire machine word, and bytes "swizzled" out of their location with some sort of shift operations.

Comment: DO support, maybe you meant?

Comment: 8086 segmented memory model.  Near pointers 16-bit, far pointers 20/32 bit.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there was some other (IBM?) machines with this sort of architecture in the distant past, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: `uintptr_t` is the size of `void *` which is also guaranteed to be big enough to hold any other pointer. Clearly, if we have a pointer with two parts, when converting to an integer, both parts needs to be stored. If the original pointer only stores one, the second part is given some default value (e.g. 0).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sure, but did you name it?  I dub it ... Chuck.

Comment: @MartinVidner The CDC 6400 had 6-bit characters and 60-bit words.  (60 is a multiple of 12 which was good because a punched card has 12 rows.)  Only 60-bit words were addressable.

Answer (score 6):

On word addressed machines a `char*` might need to contain part-word info, making it larger than an `int*`.

The standard allows this, not to rule out implementations on such hardware (even though that is even more rare now than when C89 was designed).

Comment: Linked your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29035972/1708801) do you know of other cases where `char*` has a different size than `int*`?

Answer (score 5):

The [language-lawyer](/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) tag means that you are asking about C++ and its compliant implementations, not some specific physical machine.

I'd have to quote the entire standard in order to prove it, but the simple fact is that it makes no guarantees on the result of `sizeof(T*)` for any `T`, and (as a corollary) no guarantees that `sizeof(T1*) == sizeof(T2*)` for any `T1` and `T2`).

Comment: I am. In absence of something else, I guess the `only the size of char and unsigned char` are guaranteed would do.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Sure, as long as you mention that there _are_ other contraints on some types.

Comment: "An object of type cv void* shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as cv char*"

Comment: @PlasmaHH Good find :)

Comment: Another guarantee is that "Pointers to cv-qualified and cv-unqualified versions of layout-compatible types shall have the same value representation and alignment requirements".   In C, all pointers to struct type must have same r&a but C++ doesn't appear to have that rule.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, pointers aren't guaranteed to have the same size, although on most modern architectures they are, in practice.

One point where this can be useful is when one concerns data vs. function pointers. Historically, function pointers (that are used to essentially jump to certain parts in the *executable code*) needed so-called "far pointers" which are wider than data pointers.

Answer (score 2):

I can imagine a machine where it makes sense to assume that the memory needs for `int` arrays are going to be far less than the memory needs for `char` arrays.

One may specify, for instance, that an implementation is not going to use more than 10 dynamically allocated integers, but is free to allocate many `char` arrays.  In this case, one byte may suffice for an `int*`, while a `char*` needs to be four bytes or more.

That's a theoretical vision.

Comment: More than 256 dynamically allocated integers, even, if one byte is enough.

Comment: I wanted to mention 4 bits pointers, but I thought that was over the top :)