# Is an empty vector the size of its struct?

Tags: c++, vector, struct

Say I have a struct like this:

```
struct vertexNodeInfo
{
    unsigned char level;
    int node;
    double leaf;
};
```

If I then had this:

```
vector<vertexNodeInfo> node;
```

How big (memory-wise, not `.size`) would the empty vector be, before any `push_back`? Would it be exactly the same size (again, in terms of memory) as `vector<int> node;`?

Comment: It needs enough to store a pointer to some data, the size or end of the data, and its capacity. Try `sizeof(std::vector<int>)`. The size is independent of the number of elements it holds at any given time.

Comment: @juanchopanza Actually I was hoping someone could just tell me. I'm writing a complicated DLL and I can't compile it yet. I need to know the answer before I can finish it and compile, so I can't easily test using `sizeof`.

Comment: @juanchopanza Second comment in case editing doesn't alert you of comments (forgot to put your name in when posting).

Comment: The size is unspecified, and it depends on the platform. All is required is that it holds enough data members to do what I mentioned in the first comment.

Comment: @juanchopanza All I mean is, is the memory usage of an empty `vector` affected by the data inside its `struct`?

Comment: @Clonkex typically, no. Pedantically, yes, it could be, because pointers to different types can vary in size.

Comment: @Clonkex - Depends on implementation. Anyway how on Earth does it effect the DLL and you ability to compile it?

Comment: @EdHeal What? It doesn't. Well, it doesn't affect my ability to compile it. I need to know the answer so I can decide how to write my code so I can finish writing my code so I can compile. That's all :)

Comment: @Clonkex - In what way?

Comment: I think what Ed is getting at is that you should not normally write code that depends on how much memory an empty vector occupies. In fact, since there's no guarantee about it in the standard you *can't* write portable code that depends on it. But even if there were a guarantee, it would require very unusual circumstances before anyone should need to rely on it.

Comment: @SteveJessop Actually it doesn't matter any more. I realised I only need a direct `new`/`delete` method. Now I'll ask a beginner question. Any time I use `new`, I get a pointer, right? (Obviously the var has to be declared as a pointer) What I mean is, it's not special because I used `new` on it, right? So when I pass the `new`'d var into a function, it's passing a pointer and not copying all the data of the var?

Comment: @Clonkex: What matters is the declaration of the function parameter, not where the object came from. If the function takes a pointer then you'll pass a pointer. If it takes a vector then you'll pass a vector...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no requirement. Even more, it's a poorly formulated question.

The `.size` of the vector would be `0`, because it has no elements.

The `sizeof` isn't affected the number of elements, and is typically large enough to contain one or two of pointers to the type (which can vary in size themselves, so there's no guarantee the `sizeof(vector<vertexNodeInfo>)` and `sizeof(vector<int>)` are equal), the size and capacity.

Comment: Oops, I didn't think of that. I mean in terms of memory. Obviously `.size` would be 0 :) Question edited.

Comment: @Clonkex the sizeof can vary. You could force a compiler error to find out.

Comment: So `sizeof(vector<vertexNodeInfo>)` will be bigger than `sizeof(vector<int>)`?

Comment: Just saw your other comment.

Comment: @Clonkex it could, yes. It could also be smaller. But 99% of the cases it will just be the same. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832631/can-pointers-be-of-different-sizes

Comment: So I think my question is answered :) Just out of curiosity, though, how can pointers vary in size? Wouldn't they all be a `longlong` or something?

Answer (score 1):

As Luchian says, it is likely but not required that `sizeof(vector<int>) == sizeof(vector<vertexNodeInfo>)`.

Furthermore, I don't believe the standard makes any requirement as to the `capacity` of a default-initialized vector:

[Initial capacity of vector in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271017/initial-capacity-of-vector-in-c)

So it's permitted to have a capacity of 10, meaning that it has allocated enough memory for 10 elements up front. Then the size of this allocation would of course depend on the size of the elements. You don't exactly define what you mean by "how big, memory-wise", but if you mean to include dynamic allocations then this would be one.

I don't think that would be a very *good* implementation of `vector`, but it conforms to the standard.