# §7.1.6.3/1 (C++14) doesn't accept the construction in the second snippet below. Why is this?

Tags: c++, enums, language-lawyer, c++14

**First part**:

I'm studying in some detail *opaque-enum-declaration*s and *elaborated-type-specifier*s for a few days already, and I really would like somebody to confirm this. GCC and VS2013 don't compile this code (clang does) and I believe clang is in accordance with §7.1.6.3/1, as `enum E` is an *elaborated-type-specifier* that is not the sole constituent of the declaration `enum E e = E::b;`. Is my analysis correct?

```
#include <iostream>
enum class E : char {a = 'a', b};
int E;
enum E e = E::b;        // Doesn't compile in GCC and VS2013
int main()
{
    std::cout << (char)(e) << '\n';
}
```

**Second part:**

The snippet below, which is very similar to the one above, doesn't compile. I understand why it doesn't (the *elaborated-type-specifier* `enum E` is the sole constituent of the declaration `enum E;` and §7.1.6.3/1 doesn't allow this). What I'd like to know is why can't the compiler accept this construction?

```
#include <iostream>
enum class E : char {a = 'a', b};
int E;
enum E;                 // This doesn't compile.
E e = E::b;        
int main()
{
    std::cout << (char)(e) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: For the second part, making `enum class E : char {}; enum E; ` valid but not `enum E; enum class E : char{};` would be quite...odd. [N2764](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2764.pdf) also has some relevant discussion.

Comment: This is [GCC bug#59921](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59921).

Comment: @T.C. Why odd? `enum E; enum class E: char{};` cannot be valid because of §3.4.4/1. That is, an *elaborated-type-specifier*, like `enum E` would be, is used to refer to a previous enum name, which wouldn't exist in this case.

Comment: It's inconsistent with the behavior of forward declarations of classes as well as *opaque-enum-declaration*s. And limited to the redeclaration case it doesn't really add anything useful enough to justify the extra complexity ("`enum E;` is an error, except when `E` has been previously declared to be an enumeration, in which case it is a no-op" is not very teachable or useful).

Comment: @T.C. But the example refers to an elaborated-type-specifier. It has nothing to do with forward declaration. §3.4.4/1 is clear about this.  That's why I inserted the `int E;` declaration in the code. As far as I can understand there must be another reason for the spec to disallow the declaration `enum E;` in the second snippet above.

Comment: The whole point of allowing an elaborated-type-specifier to be used like `class A;` is that it allows you to forward declare things. What, exactly, would the declaration `enum E;` do?

Comment: As for forward declaring enums please see [Why must an enumeration's size be provided when it is forward declared?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29035225/1708801) as well which covers the pointer reference case specifically which is actually very interesting case. cc @T.C.

Comment: @T.C. `The whole point of allowing an elaborated-type-specifier to be used like class A; is that it allows you to forward declare things.` I have to disagree. Look at my example (first part): `enum E` is an elaborated type specifier and it can be used to declare an enum object `e` in the declaration `enum E e = E::b;`. Consider now a forward declaration of a class A: `class A;`. If you try to declare an object of class A just after this declaration, it will not compile. (to be continued)

Comment: @T.C.  For me the two concepts are different. An elaborate-type-specifier will always start a lookup for a previous declaration, whereas in a forward declaration, this doesn't happen.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I must insist, I'm not talking about forward declarations in my examples, but about an elaborated type specifier. In summary, I don't understand why you can use `class A; A a;` where `class A` is an elaborated type specifier, but you can't use `enum E; E e;`. (to be continued)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Now in relation to a forward declaration, it's still not clear to me why this is OK: class A; void f(A*); but this is ill-formed: `enum E; void f(E*);` . See the comments to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/71495/1042389) in SO.

Comment: @Belloc maybe I am missing something but I think this is follows from the details in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29035972/1708801) since enums size can vary unless as an extension the compiler defaults enums to a particular size all the issue I mention in my answer apply. Visual Studio seems to apply this extension but is definitely not portable.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your point. `class A` is an *elaborated-type-specifier*. When you write `class A;`, a lookup *always* happens for `A`; if it is found to be a type, then this is a redeclaration; if it's not found, it's a forward declaration. But allowing you to redeclare things already declared before, by itself, is not useful. The main benefit of allowing the `class A;` syntax is that it can be used to forward declare things, a benefit that does not exist with `enum E;` as Shafik explained in the linked question.

Comment: @T.C. I've just realized there's more that I need to know about an *elaborated-type-specifier* then I thought when I started this discussion. I'll come back later to address your comment.

Comment: I take back my third sentence. `class A;` doesn't cause an unqualified name lookup, but instead unconditionally introduces the name `A` into the current scope as a *class-name*. Such a declaration can still be either a forward declaration or a redeclaration, depending on whether `A` has  already been declared in the current scope. The rest of that comment still holds - the main benefit of allowing `class A;` is to allow `A` to be forward declared.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

N4140 [basic.scope.hiding]/2:

> A class name (9.1) or enumeration name (7.2) can be hidden by the name of a variable, data member,
>   function, or enumerator declared in the same scope. If a class or enumeration name and a variable, data
>   member, function, or enumerator are declared in the same scope (in any order) with the same name, the
>   class or enumeration name is hidden wherever the variable, data member, function, or enumerator name is
>   visible.

It would appear the the declaration of `int E` hides the name of the enumeration `E` in the global scope after the `int`'s point of declaration. However, the name `E::b` is a *qualified-id* with *nested-name-specifier* of `E::`, so the rules for qualified name lookup apply. In particular, [basic.lookup.qual]/1:

> The name of a class or namespace member or enumerator can be referred to after the `::` scope resolution
>   operator (5.1) applied to a *nested-name-specifier* that denotes its class, namespace, or enumeration. If a `::`
>   scope resolution operator in a *nested-name-specifier* is not preceded by a *decltype-specifier*, **lookup of the
>   name preceding that `::` considers only namespaces, types, and templates whose specializations are types.** [*emphasis added.*]
>   If the name found does not designate a namespace or a class, enumeration, or dependent type, the program
>   is ill-formed.

So clang is conforming, GCC and MSVC are not.

Comment: Isn't the lookup for the first `E`, in the declaration `enum E e = E::b;` done before a possible lookup for the second `E`? If that is the case, I would say that the explanation for the first code to compile is more related to §7.1.6.3 and §3.3.4/1 than to  [basic.scope.hiding]/2.

Comment: @Belloc `auto e = E::b;` behaves in the same way.

Comment: @AntonSavin I believe they are not the same, as far as the lookups are concerned. In your case, I have no doubt that the explanation given by Casey is correct, as there's no elaborated-type-specifier involved.

Comment: @Belloc But GCC is complaining about the second `E`, not the first.

Comment: @T.C. Perfect! What else can I say?

Comment: Great answer (+1). I was convinced that GCC was failing to comply with §7.1.6.3/1, but T.C.'s comment above was pretty clear.

Comment: For the second part see my [comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29176179/%C2%A77-1-6-3-1-c14-doesnt-accept-the-construction-in-the-second-snippet-below#comment46574671_29176179)