# How to understand "C++ allows sizeof(char*) != sizeof(int*)"?

Tags: c++, pointers, language-lawyer

I am reading this [post](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/intrinsic-types#bytes-review) which is related to `char` and `byte`, and come across the following words:

> An `int*` could still be implemented as a single hardware pointer, since C++ allows `sizeof(char*) != sizeof(int*)`.

How to understand 'C++ allows `sizeof(char*) != sizeof(int*)`'?

Comment: What *don't* you understand about it?

Comment: @EJP: Shouldn't they be same?

Comment: @Nan: Can you explain what leads you to think that they would be? That would help us clear whatever misconception is leading you to that conclusion.

Comment: @NanXiao Only if you can find a statement in the C++ language specification that says so. Why are you removing the closing quotation mark?

Comment: @EJP: Sorry, I don't read C++ specification seriously. Just from my intuition, every pointer should has the same size, the length of machine word.

Comment: The idea may be confusing but it is possible to have different sizes for different pointer types. Look here for examples [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916051/are-there-any-platforms-where-pointers-to-different-types-have-different-sizes)

Comment: Sounds like you're thinking of pointers as glorified integers

Comment: @NanXiao infamously class pointers in [VC++ for the longest time were fat pointers, sometimes up to 16bytes or larger even on a 32bit machine](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12006854/332733). The point is that the compiler is free to make pointers whatever it wants to for purposes of optimization. So we shouldn't assume.

Comment: @Mgetz: the reasons for pointers to member functions differing in size are completely unrelated to this question.  Separately, this question's issue is *not* generally  *"for purposes of optimization"* - some systems had functional hardware reasons for pointers being of different sizes, and it would have been actively perverse and unhelpful to adopt the largest size for all so I wouldn't call not having done so an optimisation - more avoiding a crazy pessimisation.

Comment: I covered alot of this ground in my answer to [Why must an enumeration's size be provided when it is forward declared?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29035972/1708801)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the size of pointers vary in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520059/does-the-size-of-pointers-vary-in-c)

Comment: [Are there any platforms where pointers to different types have different sizes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/916051/995714), [Can the size of pointers vary between data and function pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1473935/995714)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc this is C++ not C the question may be a dupe, but not of that question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, the standard doesn't guarantee it, the result is implementation-defined.

From the standard about `sizeof` ($5.3.3/1 Sizeof [expr.sizeof])

> The sizeof operator yields the number of bytes in the object
>   representation of its operand.

and pointer is compound type ($3.9.2/1.3 Compound types [basic.compound])

> pointers to void or objects or functions (including static members of
>   classes) of a given type, 8.3.1;

and ($3.9.2/3 Compound types [basic.compound])

> The value representation of pointer types is **implementation-defined**.

even though ($3.9.2/3 Compound types [basic.compound])

> Pointers to layout-compatible types shall have the same value
>   representation and alignment requirements (3.11).

but `char` and `int` don't need to have the same value representation. The starndard only says ($3.9.1/2 Fundamental types [basic.fundamental])

> There are five standard signed integer types : “signed char”, “short
>   int”, “int”, “long int”, and “long long int”. In this list, each type
>   provides at least as much storage as those preceding it in the list.

and ($3.9.1/3 Fundamental types [basic.fundamental]) etc.

> each signed integer type has the same object representation as its
>   corresponding unsigned integer type.

Answer (score 3):

There are (or were) machines which could only address entire "words", where a word was large enough to hold several characters. For example, the PDP-6/10 had a word-size of 36-bits. On such a machine, you might implement 9-bit bytes and represent a byte pointer as the combination of a word pointer and a bit-index within the word. A naïve implementation would require two words for such a pointer, even though a integer pointer would be just a word pointer, occupying a single word.

(The real PDP-6/10 allowed for smaller character sizes -- 6- and 7-bit codings were common, depending on use case -- and since a pointer could not occupy a whole word, it was possible to make a character pointer including bit offset and word address fit inside a single word. But a similar architecture these days would not have the draconian restriction on address space, so that wouldn't work anymore.)

Answer (score 2):

*itsnotmyrealname* and *rici* touch on the hardware drivers for this, but I thought it might help to walk through the simplest possible scenario leading to different pointer sizes...

Imagine a CPU that can address 32-bit words of memory, and that the C++ `int` type is also to be 32 bits wide.

This hypothetical CPU addresses specific words using a numbering: 0 for the first word (bytes 0-3), 1 for the second (bytes 4-7) and so on.  `int*{0}` is therefore your first word in memory (assuming no bizarre `nullptr` shenanigans require otherwise), `int*{1}` the second etc..

What should the compiler do to support 8-bit `char` types?  It may have to implement `char*` support using an `int*` to identify the word in memory, but still need an extra two bits to store 0, 1, 2 or 3 to say which of the bytes in that word are being pointed to.  It would effectively need to generate machine code much as a C++ program might if using...

```
struct __char_ptr
{
    unsigned* p_;
    unsigned byte_ : 2;
    char get() const { return (*p_ & (0xFF << (8*byte_)) >> 8*byte_; }
    void set(char c) { *p_ &= ~(0xFF << (8*byte_)); *p |= c << 8*byte_; }
};
```

On such a system - `sizeof(__char_ptr) > sizeof(int*)`.  The C++ Standard's flexibility allows compliant C++ implementations for (and code portability to/from) weird systems with this or similar issues.

Answer (score 2):

This is also the reason why [we can not forward declare enums without providing the underlying size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29035972/1708801) in my answer I provide several references that cover why this is so.

in this [comp.lang.c++ discussion: GCC and forward declaration of enum](http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.c++/gcc-and-forward-declaration-of-enum/1005825):

> [...] While on most architectures it may not be an issue, on some
>   architectures the pointer will have a different size, in case it is a
>   char pointer. [...]

and we can find from this C-Faq entry [Seriously, have any actual machines really used nonzero null pointers, or different representations for pointers to different types?](http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html)  it says:

> Older, word-addressed Prime machines were also notorious for requiring larger byte pointers (char *'s) than word pointers (int *'s). [...] Some 64-bit Cray machines represent int * in the lower 48 bits of a word; char * additionally uses some of the upper 16 bits to indicate a byte address within a word. [...]

and furthermore:

> [...]The Eclipse MV series from Data General has three architecturally supported pointer formats (word, byte, and bit pointers), two of which are used by C compilers: byte pointers for char * and void *, and word pointers for everything else. For historical reasons during the evolution of the 32-bit MV line from the 16-bit Nova line, word pointers and byte pointers had the offset, indirection, and ring protection bits in different places in the word. Passing a mismatched pointer format to a function resulted in protection faults. Eventually, the MV C compiler added many compatibility options to try to deal with code that had pointer type mismatch errors. [...] The old HP 3000 series uses a different addressing scheme for byte addresses than for word addresses; like several of the machines above it therefore uses different representations for char * and void * pointers than for other pointers. [...]

Answer (score 1):

The standard says:

> **5.3.3 Sizeof**
>   sizeof(char) , sizeof(signed char) and sizeof(unsigned char) are 1 . 
>   The result of sizeof applied to any other fundamental type (
>   3.9.1 ) is implementation-defined.

Since pointers are "compound types", and the standard makes no mention of byte size consistency between pointers, the compiler writers are free to do as they wish.

Comment: He said `sizeof(char*)`, not `char`. He's asking about why two pointers may not have the same size.

Comment: @NicolBolas That comes under 'any other fundamental type'. A pointer to a fundamental type is a fundamental type unless I am greatly mistaken.

Comment: @EJP: Nope. Pointers are not fundamental types. They are compound types.

Comment: @EJP Yes.  It seems "std::is_compound<char*>::value" emits true