# C++11 Enum forward causes "underlying type mismatch"

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, g++, forward-declaration

I'm working in C++11 and including an h file implemented in C++03. In the h file I'm including there's an enum `Foo` defined. I want to declare a forward to it in `code.h` and use it in `code.cpp`:

header.h:

```
enum Foo {A=1};
```

code.h:

```
enum Foo : int; // also tried : unsigned int, long, short, unsigned short, char, unsigned char
void bar(Foo foo);
```

code.cpp:

```
#include header.h
void bar(Foo foo) { }
```

This is the error I get when I compile (tested g++ 4.8.5 and g++ 5.3.1):

```
In file included from code.cpp:2:0:
header.h:1:6: error: underlying type mismatch in enum ‘enum Foo’
 enum Foo {A=1};
      ^
In file included from code.cpp:1:0:
code.h:3:12: error: previous definition here
 enum Foo : int;
```

I can fix this error if I change header.h to:

```
enum Foo : int {A=1};
```

But I don't own that header and can't change it. Taking the error at face value, it sounds like all I need to know is what type g++ uses for enums which don't specify underlying type, then use that type in my forward.

[Even this simple example doesn't work](http://cpp.sh/4liwz) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

enum Foo {A=1};
enum Foo : unsigned; // : std::underlying_type<Foo>::type also doesn't work

int main()
{

  std::cout << "Hello, world\n";
}
```

Comment: Well, the C++ Standard explicitly forbids this (forward-declaring an enumeration requires a fixed underlying type). Maybe another solution is possible, like wrapping the enum in a struct?

Comment: Reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71416/forward-declaring-an-enum-in-c, I thought it was possible in C++11.

Comment: Since C++11, you can forward-declare an enumeration, but this requires fixing the underlying type ("specifying an enum-base"), and repeating the same underlying type for each declaration (forward-declaration or actual declaration). So if you can't add an underlying type to the external header, then you cannot (are not allowed to) forward-declare this enumeration.

Comment: `std::underlying_type` tells you the underlying type of an `enum`.  What does it say for your enum?

Comment: @Yakk, `unsigned`. Yet if I do `enum Foo : unsigned` - I get the error above.

Comment: Also this doesn't work: `enum Foo : std::underlying_type::type;` nor this: `enum Foo : std::underlying_type<Foo1>::type;` (where `Foo1` is just some enum)

Comment: Interestingly, using a scoped enum,  `enum struct Foo : int` seems to work, but anything other than the type `int` throws the same error.

Comment: Related [Why must an enumeration's size be provided when it is forward declared?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29035225/1708801)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any way of doing this, even if you specify the exact same *underlying type* that the compiler would have chosen for your C++03-style `enum`.

Example: compiling the following code...

```
enum Foo { A=1 };
cout << typeid(typename std::underlying_type<Foo>::type).name();
```

...[on Coliru and demangling via `c++filt`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7b37f422154b18b) will print `"unsigned int"` both with **g++** and **clang++**.

Even if you specify `unsigned int` as the explicit *underlying type* of your `Foo` *forward declaration*, [both compilers will complain](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/edb30c4e1437b0fe).

```
enum Foo : unsigned int;
void bar(Foo);

enum Foo {A=1};
```

```
main.cpp:8:6: error: enumeration previously declared with fixed underlying type
enum Foo {A=1};
     ^
main.cpp:5:6: note: previous declaration is here
enum Foo : unsigned int;
     ^
```

This is because both the *forward declaration* and the "real" `enum` declaration need to have the same **explicit** underlying type, even if you manage to "guess" what the compiler would have chosen for you.

---

**tl;dr**: you can only forward-declare an `enum` if both the forward-declaration and the real declaration have the same **explicitly specified** underlying type.

Comment: By the way, VisualStudio (can't remember which version) accepted mismatches between specifications of the underlying type (as an extension). This leads to dangerous mismatches where the size of the enumeration is different within the same translation unit, and even incorrect code. I think it's a good idea to enforce consistency between enumeration declarations regarding the specification of an underlying type.

Comment: on g++ (7.4) the `cout` line in the example code above doesn't compile. It should be `std::underlying_type<Foo>::type` not `std::underlying_type_t<Foo>::type`

Answer (score 6):

You can only forward declare an enum if you give it a fixed underlying type in the forward declaration. Also, the definition of the enum must use the *same* fixed underlying type.

Your problem is that your enum definition in `header.h` doesn't have an underlying type, but the later forward declaration has one. They *both* must have one.

Comment: I'm starting to understand that this won't work, but I don't see any reason for it not to. At least this should be possible: `enum Foo : std::underlying_type<Foo>::type`. What I'm saying is that there's always an underlying type, just in C++03 style it's implicit.

Comment: @ytoledano: You're asking the compiler to determine the implicit underlying type of an enum that has *not yet been defined*. That's *impossible*. The compiler has not seen the definition of `Foo`, and therefore, `std::underlying_type<Foo>::type` is not legal syntax. The implicit underlying type is based on the definition of `Foo`, which is in a header that you didn't include (and if you did, there's no point in forward declaring the enum).

Answer (score 2):

As of my todays version of gcc, you have to define the exact type twice, not only in the forward *declaration* but as well in the *definition*:

```
enum Foo : int;
```

...

```
enum Foo : int {A=1};
```

This worked for me, compiler is gcc 7.3.0.