# Pointers and their size in C

Tags: c

I have tried to wrap my head around this for some time now, and have searched for related questions. I have found some answers that make some sense, but apparently I need this carved in stone.

Currently I'm in the process of learning some firmware for a product. A set of pointers have been initialized as `uint8_t`, like the following example:

```
uint8_t *pwhatevs;
```

The `sizeof` the above would return `1` (one byte). When this pointer is assigned later in the firmware, it is pointing to a 32-bit address in the following way:

```
pwhatevs = (uint8_t *)&whatever;
```

This syntax appears odd to me. The initial part `(uint8_t *)` is an 8-bit pointer typecast. But if I take the `sizeof pwhatevs` now it returns `4` (4 bytes), which I'm both not surprised of but then again very surprised due to the pointer typecast. Can someone explain this? If additional information is needed I will provide as much as I can!

**Edit:** In another question relating to pointer size it was mentioned that the size of a pointer is system dependent like 16, 32 or 64 bits. This does make sense, but then why is the `*pwhatevs` when initialized not 4 bytes in size?

**Edit 2:** I can't share the entire code since it is an actual product, but will do it the following way. If this isn't sufficient, I will have to work on a specific example.

[image: code]

[image: Variables with assigned size from code]

Comment: It depends on the addressing of the platform you are running, 32 bits is the addressbus size, in other words the pointer size will always be 4byte

Comment: `The sizeof the above would return 1 (one byte)` Please show your code. `Can someone explain this?` I challenge the method of measurement into question. I suspect you made an error in your code. I doubt a pointer size has a sizeof of 1. `why is the *pwhatevs` The sizeof of *pwhatevs is 1, the sizeof of pwhatevs could be 4. Please be exact, please show the code.

Comment: "_pointers have been initialized as uint8_t_" Pointers are pointers that are the size of pointers (that hold addresses). The example given has been initialised as "**uint8_t *;**" It is a "pointer to things that are unsigned _single_ bytes."

Comment: Kraego, please see my edit note :) My thought is that when the pointer is made to point to an actual address then the (uint_8 *) typecast is "forced" to (uint32_t) due to the addressbus size. Would that make sense?

Comment: It s like Fe203 said you can see the pointer type as hint to what the pointer is pointing, the address would always have the same size regardless to what it points

Comment: `double *pDbl;` declares a pointer (4 bytes on your system?) that will be used to point to an 8 byte _object_ (a `double`)... For a purpose (such as serialising those bytes for transmission), you might write something like `uint8_t *p8 = (uint8_t *) pDbl;`. You can then deal with those 8 bytes individually... Does this help?

Comment: Addresses come in 1-size for a given processor. Your addresses are 4-bytes according to your question -- so pointers (which are just normal variables that hold the address of something else) must be capable of holding 4-bytes. Your declaration `uint8_t *foo` just means `foo` is a pointer to a `uint8_t`, the `uint8_t` has nothing to do with the `sizeof (a_pointer);` it's just the type being *pointed to...*

Comment: Confusing `sizeof(pwhatevs)` and `sizeof(*pwhatevs)` , i.e. sizeof pointer vs sizeof element pointed by.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are confusing the size of the pointer with the size of the thing the pointer *points to*.

For a most platforms you encounter today (x86, ARM, etc), *all pointers will **always** be the same size*<sup>1</sup>, regardless of the type they point to. For a platform with a 32 bit address space, pointers will likely be 4 bytes (32 bits) long. There is no such thing as an "8-bit pointer typecast": the `(uint8_t*)` type is "a pointer to an 8-bit variable", not an "8-bit pointer".

For your example:

`(sizeof pwhatevs) == 4` <-- The size of the pointer type *itself*: (`sizeof (uint8_t*)`). This might also be 2 or 8, depending on the platform.

`(sizeof *pwhatevs) == 1` <-- The size of the type the pointer *points to* (`sizeof (uint8_t)`)

Most importantly, the `sizeof` of anything in C can never change<sup>2</sup>. Once a variable is declared it has a fixed `sizeof`. It is not possible that assigning something to a pointer changes its size. You are doing something wrong when measuring its size, but without your **complete** code it is impossible to tell what.

---

<sup>1</sup> For more in-depth information, see for example [Can pointers be of different sizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832631/can-pointers-be-of-different-sizes)

<sup>2</sup> Of course the size of a variable can be different if you compile the same code for a different platform, or on a different operating system, or with different compiler flags. But it can never change during a single compilation process of a single `.c` file. Not by assignments, nor by anything else.

Comment: Re “For a given platform, *all pointers will **always** be the same size*, regardless of the type they point to”: This is not true. Most modern C implementations use one size for all pointer types, but the C standard does not require it, and there are C implementations that have pointers of different sizes. (The standard does require certain categories of some types of pointers to be the same size.)

Comment: Good point, although I think that this (today mostly irrelevant) fact would be too confusing for a beginner who is struggling with the basic concept of pointer types. I will adjust the text.

Comment: I'm well aware it would be ideal with the complete code, but unfortunately I can't post that. The answer you have provided is also my understanding of it. But would the (uint8_t *) not be redundant in this context? 

pwhatevs = (uint8_t *) &whatever;

Comment: @TheLostProgrammer If you cannot post the whole code, then you should post a minimal, reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Chances are, you will figure it out yourself while you do that (happens to all of us). If `whatever` is a `uint8_t`, then that type cast is indeed redundant. And it is bad practice as it would hide an error message if someone later changed the type of `whatever` but forgot to change the type of `pwhatevs`. But type casting has nothing to do with the sizes of the types/pointers in question. As I said, pointer sizes don't change.

Answer (score -1):

- > `uint8_t *pwhatevs;` The sizeof the above would return 1 (one byte).

  No it wouldn't, have you tried? `sizeof(pwhatevs)` will equal the size of the address bus, which on all mainstream computers will be either 2, 4 or 8 bytes. `sizeof(*pwatevs)` will however return 1 since that's the size of the pointed-at type. The problem here seems to be that you confuse the type pointed at with the pointer variable itself.
- > This syntax appears odd to me. The initial part (uint8_t *) is an 8 bit pointer typecast.

  Again, there is no such thing as "an 8 bit pointer typecast". This is rather a cast to a pointer pointing at an 8-bit type. The size of the pointer and the size of the pointed-at type are different things.
- > But if I take the sizeof pwhatevs now it returns 4

  It did that all along, regardless of what the pointer pointed at. You cannot change the size of pointers in C, they have a fixed size determined by the compiler, based on what's suitable for the given CPU.