# for loop help. Terminates when it isnt supposed to. c++

Tags: c++, for-loop

I'm new to stackoverflow, but i did try to look for an answer and could not find it. I also can't seem to figure it out myself. So for a school C++ project, we need to find the area under a curve. I have all the formulas hardcoded in, so don't worry about that. And so the program is supposed to give a higher precision answer with a higher value for (n). But it seems that when I put a value for (n) thats higher than (b), the program just loops a 0 and does not terminate. Could you guys help me please. Thank you. Heres the code:

```
/* David */

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

cout << "Please Enter Lower Limit: " << endl;
int a;
cin >> a;

cout << "Please Enter Upper Limit: " << endl;
int b;
cin >> b;

cout << "Please Enter Sub Intervals: " << endl;
int n;
cin >> n;

double Dx = (b - a) / n;
double A = 0;
double X = a;

for (X = a; X <= (b - Dx); X += Dx)
{
    A = A + (X*X*Dx);
    X = X * Dx;
    cout << A << endl;
}

cout << "The area under the curve is: " << A << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `X = X * Dx;` What is this one for? It doesn't make much sense.

Comment: That was one mistake that I ended up finding. It's supposed to be x=x+DX;

Comment: But you already have `X += Dx` in the `for` loop. Do you want to increment `X` twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a`, `b`, `n` are integers. So the following:

```
(b - a) / n
```

is probably 0. You can replace it with:

```
double(b - a) / n
```

Answer (score 1):

Since all the variables in `(b - a) / n` are `int`, you're doing integer division, which discards fractions in the result. Assigning to a `double` doesn't change this.

You should convert at least one of the variables to `double` so that you'll get a floating point result with the fractions retained:

```
double Dx = (b - a) / (double)n;
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct. Your problem is probably integer division. You have to cast on of the operands to double.

But you should use [static_cast<> instead of C-style casts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609163/what-is-the-difference-between-static-cast-and-c-style-casting). Namely use

```
static_cast<double>(b - a) / n
```

instead of `double(b - a) / n` or `((double) (b - a)) / n`.

Comment: So you rather add 10 more characters to do an int to double conversion?

Comment: Yes, I definitely would. C style casts are discouraged in C++ code. And not using them at all allows you do enable compile flags like `-Wold-style-cast` that could help you spot accidental C style casts that might be more error prone than int to double.

Comment: I think it's wise to wear a seat belt but not to drive at 5 mph.

Answer (score 0):

You are performing integer division. Integer division will only return whole numbers by cutting off the decimal:

```
3/2 == 1 //Because 1.5 will get cut to 1
3/3 == 1
3/4 == 0 //Because 0.5 will get cut to 0
```

You need to have at least one of the two values on the left or right of the "/" be a decimal type.

```
3 / 2.0f == 1.5f
3.0f / 2 == 1.5f
3.0f / 2.0f == 1.5f
```