# If I want to promote a char to an int, should I use static_cast<int>(char variable) or +(char variable) and why?

Tags: c++, static-cast, unary-operator, integer-promotion

This question is a little subjective, but I believe it may lead to some constructive answers. Assume I have `char x;` and I want to promote it to an integral so I can access it's numeric value. Which should I prefer to use and why? `static_cast<int>` or unary arithmetic operator `+`?

My own thoughts are that using a `static_cast<int>` is more explicit and readable. However, using the unary arithmetic operator `+` is shorter code.

Is one way safer than the other?

Comment: Just a note as it's easy to overlook: as `char` may be signed or unsigned, when you specifically want an `int` in the range 0..255 you need something like `static_cast<int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(c))`.

Comment: @TonyD Not following that last part. Don't you mean `static_cast<unsigned int>(x)` or `static_cast<int>(x)` for `x` is _unsigned char_ and _signed char_ respectively?

Comment: If the implementation's `char` type happens to be signed, then you start with a -128..127 value: if you cast that straight to `unsigned int` then negative values become "huge" positive values, while `static_cast<int>` for a signed `char` still gives you -128..127 values, which is why you want to cast it to `unsigned char`: then you're dealing with a 0..255 value. The outer `static_cast<int>(...)`: sorry, shouldn't have mentioned it in this context (I use it when streaming the ASCII value so I get the `operator<<(int)` overload giving e.g. "65" and not `operator<<(char)` e.g. 'A').

Comment: @TonyD I'm following you a bit better now but I have one small confusion. What if you have a `signed char` that's negative, let's say -65. Would we still want to have a range from 0..255 for our `int` and if so, wouldn't static casting our `signed char` to an `unsigned char` also overflow giving us an undesired cast to `int`?

Comment: @TonyD It took me a while but I figured out the answer to my own confusion. For every negative char value there exists a positive char value from 128 - 255 inclusive. These positive char values share the same binary number as their negative counterparts. For example, -1 is 1111 1111 in binary and 255 is 1111 1111 in binary. This is because there is no way to know if a binary number is negative or positive unless you are told it is a signed value. In which case, you refer to the left most number. If it is a 1, it's negative. If it is a 0, it's positive. So in this case, your logic makes sense.

Comment: Because if I were to `static_cast<unsigned char>(signed char)` and let's say our signed char is `-1`. Then it would be cast to `255` since they both have the same binary value. And so, we can safely cast it again to an integer and know that it's value will be from 0..255.

Comment: just seen your last three posts, and you have indeed worked it all out beautifully. Might be time for a new nickname ;-). Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, there is one important advantage of using `static_cast`, even if it is a little bit more verbose: it allows you to quickly search your code for casts via `grep` or any other text searching utility. In large projects this may make the difference, since otherwise C-style casts are often mistakenly matched in functions declarations such as `void f(double)`, where `(double)` is of course not a cast.

Moreover, `static_cast` makes perfectly clear your intention. Using the `+` operator may seem exotic (incomprehensible) to someone who is not 100% familiar with integer promotions rules. In terms of "safety", afaik, both are equally good.

Related: [What is the difference between static_cast<> and C style casting?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1609163/3093378)

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I'll prefer to use `static_cast`. It's important that others know what I'm trying to do in my code.

Comment: Answer as per Scott myers and he has a more verbose reasoning