# Can Preprocessor values be used for arithmetic in C?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

While working on a project, I stumbled upon an issue. Some arithmetic using Preprocessor defined values resulted in `0.00`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PINGCOUNT 10

int main()
{
    int successful = 5;
    int lossPercentage = ((PINGCOUNT - successful) / PINGCOUNT) * 100;
    printf("%.2lf\n", lossPercentage);

    return 0;
}
```

I re-ran this code in an online compiler and got the same result. I'm not sure if I am wording this poorly, but I'm having trouble finding information about this topic online.

The above code would work if I first declared `int count = PINGCOUNT`, then replaced the `PINGCOUNT` instances with `count`. Additionally, I tried using `PINGCOUNT` in some simple subtraction/addition and it worked properly. Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: `#define PINGCOUNT ((int)10)` or `#define PINGCOUNT ((double)10)`

Comment: also integers are **whole** values. only float or double can be fractions.

Comment: @user42187 : I wonder how the above code would work if you first declared int count = PINGCOUNT, then replaced the PINGCOUNT instances with count.  It works but still gives you 0.00. doesn't it?

Answer (score 3):

Since everything is an `int` in your program, you're doing integer division, so `(PINGCOUNT - successful) / PINGCOUNT` equals to `0`, which multiplied by `100` is still `0`.

Then, you're trying to print the result as a `double`, which invokes *undefined behaviour*.

Changing this line

```
int lossPercentage = ((PINGCOUNT - successful) / PINGCOUNT) * 100;
```

to:

```
double lossPercentage = (PINGCOUNT - successful) * 100.0 / PINGCOUNT;
```

makes sure the result is of type `double`, performing the operations as you intended.

Comment: Ah, I definitely overlooked the fact that it was integer division. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try :
int lossPercentage = (PINGCOUNT - successful) * 100 / PINGCOUNT;

it's simply a problem with integers ,
(PINGCOUNT - successful) / PINGCOUNT)
is equal 0 and * 100 is still 0

Comment: I wasn't realizing that I was dividing integers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Can Preprocessor values be used for arithmetic in C?

Yes.

> But why you shouldn't use macros?

Because they rearrange the program text before
the compiler proper sees it, macros are also a major problem for many programming support tools. (Courtesy : Bjane Stroustrup)

Though he said that in a C++ perspective, it is equally
applicable to C programs as well.

> Now what happened in your program

You are getting unexpected results not because you have used a preprocessor
value in your calculation. It is because you have used a type that cannot
store floating point values, ie **int**.

You could in fact change

```
int lossPercentage = ((PINGCOUNT - successful) / PINGCOUNT) * 100;
```

to

```
double lossPercentage = ((PINGCOUNT - successful) / PINGCOUNT) * 100;
```

An alternative would be to use C-Style cast in your preprocessor definition.

Change

```
#define PINGCOUNT 10
```

to

```
#define PINGCOUNT ((float)10)
```

and retain

```
int lossPercentage = ((PINGCOUNT - successful) / PINGCOUNT) * 100;
```

But you lose precision here and there is a cost associated with C-Style Cast - Problems can only be
found at run-time. See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609163/what-is-the-difference-between-static-cast-and-c-style-casting).

Comment: Sorry, the original code was :
   double lossPercentage = ((PINGCOUNT - successful) / PINGCOUNT) * 100;
but this still produces 0 as a result.

Comment: Did the use of c-style cast in the preprocessor directive work for you?

Comment: Stroustrup's comments about macros are nice and all.... C++ has a (horrifying) templates system that can do most of the things that can be done with macros. C doesn't. In C sometimes macros is the best way to do something. That or perl...