# Does a static_cast make sense on a getInt() function?

Tags: c++, qt, static-cast

Does this statis cast make sense **FOR THIS EXPLICIT CASE**?

```
QSqlQuery q;
enum MyEnumType;
obj.setMyEnumType(static_cast<MyEnumType>(q.value(2).toInt()));
```

or is a static cast for situations where the source type is not sure int?

the set function is

```
 void setMyEnumType(MyEnumTypetype type) { m_type = type; }
```

what is the advantage to a simple cast?

```
obj.setMyEnumType((MyEnumType)q.value(2).toInt());
```

Comment: yes it does, as without it this code will fail to compile

Comment: @slava you are right it accepty enum, but compiles even without static_cast

Comment: without static_cast you mean your example with C style cast? Yes that would compile, but you just replaced one cast with another.

Comment: yes but the c-style writes shorter, has the static_cast any difference to the c-cast in my case?

Comment: static_cast is better as it is easier to catch and it is more restrictive than c-style cast

Comment: yes generally of course, but in my case the toInt() can only return int in every case

Comment: Its better to have proper safe habits rather than write expression couple symbols shorter in particular case.

Answer (score 3):

Yes the cast makes perfect sense.  Let's unpick this a little more:

```
QSqlQuery q;
enum MyEnumType;
const auto v1 = q.value(2);  // I don't know what the type of v1 will be.
                             // See the QSqlQuery docs.
const auto v2 = v1.toInt();  // v2 is going to be an int or a long or something.

obj.setMyEnumType(v2);       // Error: setMyEnumType doesn't take an int argument.

const auto e = static_cast<MyEnumType>(v2);
obj.setMyEnumType(e);        // OK.  Argument is now the right type.
```

**Edit:** Ah-ha!  I see now you were asking an entirely different question.  The question you were really asking is a duplicate of [What is the difference between static_cast<> and C style casting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609163/what-is-the-difference-between-static-cast-and-c-style-casting)

Always prefer `static_cast` because a) a code reviewer will be prompted to think "what happens if the value is out of range?"; b) a code reviewer *won't* have to think "is this a static_cast, a reinterpret cast, a const cast, or some combination of all three - and is it safe?"

Comment: of course, but in my case the source-type is clear

Comment: @wutzebaer: I don't understand your comment.  I have just split the single expression which evaluated the argument to `setMyEnumType` into multiple  expressions, and saved the intermediate values in named variables.

Answer (score 1):

It makes perfect sense to convert from `int` to an `enum` and back. You might check for boundary conditions (e.g., int is larger than last element of enum). Note that you're not casting the function here, but the return value.

Comment: does static_cast automatically make a boundary check?

Comment: @wutzebaer No it does not.

Comment: so whats the advantage of the static_cast in this case?

Comment: @wutzebaer there is no implicit conversion from `int` to `enum`

Comment: no implicit, but `obj.setMyEnumType((MyEnumType)q.value(2).toInt());` works too

Comment: @wutzebaer but? this is explicit c-cast

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit of an XY problem in this scenario, as `QVariant` provides built-in conversion safety checks and casting.

Use [`qvariant_cast`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#qvariant_cast) or [`QVariant::value<>()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#value), alongside `canConvert()`, e.g.:

```
QVariant v = q.value(2);
if (v.canConvert<MyEnumType>()) {
    obj.setEnumType( qvariant_cast<MyEnumType>(v));
    ...
}
```