# c++ avoid code duplication when introducing additional interface to some classes of inheritance tree

Tags: c++, inheritance

Following is a model example. Suppose I have class `Creature` that has three coordinates x,y,z. I also have inheritance tree:

```
class Creature {
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;
};
class Mammal : public Creature {common code for mammals};
class Wolf : public Mammal;
class Bat : public Mammal; 
class Birds : public Creature {common code for birds};
class Penguin : public Bird;
class Crow : public Bird;
```

Some creatures can fly, so they should have following member function (implementation is same for all creatures):

```
void fly(int height) {z = height;}
```

So I do the following:

```
class FlyingMammal : public Mammal {
  void fly(int height) {z = height;}
  //'z' is also used in some methods of non-flying creatures, 
  //so it can't be moved to FlyingMammal class.    
};
class Wolf : public Mammal;
class Bat : public FlyingMammal;
class FlyingBird : public Bird {
  void fly(int height) {z = height;}
};
class Penguin : public Bird;
class Crow : public FlyingBird;
```

However, I have code duplication in FlyingMammal and FlyingBird. Is there standard pattern to avoid it? I suppose some kind of multiple inheritance might fit here, but don't know how exactly to do it.

Note that additional interface like `fly()` does not introduce new data members, only new member functions. But it uses member data `z` of `Creature` class.

Comment: Try creating a static method that holds the common code, then use that method in the flying bird and mammal classes.

Comment: Yes, but I would prefer moving the interface **with** implementation to some kind of `IFly` class, **if it is possible**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)
 would be one way to go ... like so

```
template <typename TThisClass>
class Flier
{
public:
    void fly(int z) { static_cast<TThisClass *>(this)->setZ(z); } 
};

class Creature {
private:
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;
public:
  void setX(int x) { this->x = x; }
  void setY(int y) { this->y = y; }
  void setZ(int z) { this->z = z; }
  // add setter & getter for x, y, z
};

class Mammal : public Creature { /*common code for mammals*/};

class Wolf : public Mammal { };

class Bat : public Mammal, public Flier<Bat> { };

class Bird : public Creature { /*common code for birds*/ };

class Penguin : public Bird { };

class Crow : public Bird, public Flier<Crow> { };

int main(int, char **) { Crow c; c.fly(1000); };
```

Comment: Very nice, this is exactly what I need. I could not come up with `static_cast` trick.  I would also appreciate if someone else confirms that there is no hidden danger because of `static_cast`.

Comment: @DmitryJ  static_cast is safe(st) . [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609163/what-is-the-difference-between-static-cast-and-c-style-casting) is a question on that.