# C++ polymorphism different virtual functions can be called by same function name?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Class1 {
public:
    virtual void f() {
        cout << "Function f() in Class1\n";
    }
};
class Class2 {
public:
    virtual void h() {
        cout << "Function h() in Class2\n";
    }
};
int main() {
    Class1 object1, *p;
    Class2 object2;
    p = &object1;
    p = (Class1*)&object2;
    p->f();//possibly abnormal program termination. but in fact, it will call function h(),Why?
    return 0;
}
```

The code must be wrong in theory because `p->f()` there is no function **f()** in the **Class2**.

But in fact, the code can be run, and it will call Function **h()** in the **Class2**, It's so strange,why??

Comment: Because undefined behavior.

Comment: There is no polymorphism here.  `Class1` and `Class2` are unrelated and the behavior of your code is undefined.

Comment: `object2` is not an instance of `Class1`, but (using an explicit type conversion that stops the compiler complaining) you force `p` to point at it.  Calling `p->f()` then gives undefined behaviour.   When behaviour is undefined, any result is possible, whether it makes sense to you or not.

Comment: p = (Class1*)&object2; Do not use this kind of cast anyway. You should use static_cast<Class1*>(&object2); That would be a compile error. It is a good idea to NEVER use C-style casts in C++ code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609163/what-is-the-difference-between-static-cast-and-c-style-casting

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with the code, and as @tkausi commented, the behavior is undefined.

The problem is that you are using C-style cast which is dangerous and should be avoided in C++. From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast):

> When the C-style cast expression is encountered, the compiler
>   attempts to interpret it as the following cast expressions, in this
>   order:
>
> 1. `const_cast<new_type>(expression);`
> 2. `static_cast<new_type>(expression)`, with extensions: pointer or
>      reference to a derived class is additionally allowed to be cast to
>      pointer or reference to unambiguous base class (and vice versa) even
>      if the base class is inaccessible (that is, this cast ignores the
>      private inheritance specifier). Same applies to casting pointer to
>      member to pointer to member of unambiguous non-virtual base;
> 3. `static_cast` (with extensions) followed by `const_cast`;
> 4. `reinterpret_cast<new_type>(expression);`
> 5. `reinterpret_cast` followed by `const_cast`.
>
> The first choice that satisfies the requirements of
>   the respective cast operator is selected, even if it cannot be
>   compiled (see example). If the cast can be interpreted in more than
>   one way as `static_cast` followed by a `const_cast`, it cannot be
>   compiled.  In addition, C-style cast notation is allowed to cast from,
>   to, and between pointers to incomplete class type. If both expression
>   and `new_type` are pointers to incomplete class types, it's unspecified
>   whether `static_cast` or `reinterpret_cast` gets selected.

Thus, in your case the compiler will select `reinterpret_cast` which will just reinterpret the raw bytes of your object as something else (and it just happens that the first thing in the virtual table of `p` points to method `h`).

To make your program safe, you should instead use `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast`:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Class1 {
public:
    virtual void f() {
        cout << "Function f() in Class1\n";
    }
};
class Class2 {
public:
    virtual void h() {
        cout << "Function h() in Class2\n";
    }
};
int main() {
    Class1 object1, *p;
    Class2 object2;
    p = &object1;
    p = static_cast<Class1*>(&object2); // fails to compile
    p->f();
    return 0;
}
```

In this case, compilation fails as expected.
Live example: https://godbolt.org/g/noErNr

Note that if we replace `static_cast` line with `p = dynamic_cast<Class1*>(&object2);` the code will compile, but `p` will be set to `nullptr` at runtime, and trying to call `p->f()` will result in an error.

Answer (score 3):

C++ doesn't have many run-time checks for performance reasons, so it will just do what you tell it to do even if it is illogical.

You are telling it to call the virtual method `Class1::f` on a pointer organised in the memory layout of `Class2` and apparently `Class2::h` aligns with `Class1::f` so it gets called.

This is not standardised behaviour and may differ between compilers. See [Virtual method table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table).

Answer (score 1):

> The code must be wrong in theory because p->f() there is no function
>   f() in the Class2.

The code is not only wrong in theory, but it is wrong in pratice too. The thing is that C++ does not hold your hand and does not wrap you in cotton wool, if you do wrong stuff, bad things can happen. Typesafety is your friend, but if you betray it, you are on your own.

In this line:

```
p = (Class1*)&object2;
```

you pretend that you could cast a `Class2` to a `Class1`. Anything beyond that is undefined behaviour, which is sloopy speaking a way of saying: c++ does not care what is the output of programs that dont obey the rules.

The way to stay friends with the typesystem is to use [`static_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) instead of a C-style cast, which would tell you that the cast is not allowed.