# Is there any advantage in static_casting an int to enum instead of just initializing it directly?

Tags: c++, enums, casting, static-cast

Is it in any way safer/"better" to do:

```
enum ENUM { // can be enum class too
...
};
int incoming_value_from_other_process;
auto e = static_cast<ENUM>(incoming_value_from_other_process);
```

than

```
auto e = ENUM(incoming_value_from_other_process); // more compact and readable, faster to type
```

**EDIT** : this is for intra-process and/or networking communication where enums are just serialized in messages and then directly converted.

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't be doing either since you have no guarantee that the value you are specifying is a valid enum value.

Comment: With just the tiny example you have given us, I don't see the point in any of them. Why not just assign the relevant enum value ? Not doing it defeats the purpose of the enums' static types. The only use-case in which imo it is relevant to static_cast from an int is when you are doing networking/intraprocess communication

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between static\_cast<> and C style casting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609163/what-is-the-difference-between-static-cast-and-c-style-casting)

Comment: @Xatyrian -- it's legal and often useful to assign values to a variable of an enumerated type that do not correspond to the value of any of the enumerators.

Comment: @PeteBecker I have no doubt that it is legal but it feels like a code smell to me.

Comment: @Xatyrian It's for intra-process/networking communication

Comment: The thing is, I thought that this is *not* c-style casting, but actually enum-value-initialization, like saying `auto i = int(5);`

Comment: There's nothing wrong about C-style casts (as long as you don't cast to pointers/references). I'd use `auto e = ENUM(5);` (or `ENUM e = ENUM(5);`).

Comment: @Xatyrian -- the standard goes out of its way to define the range of values that can be assigned to an enumerated type. Basically, you can use any of the bits that are needed for the various defined values. That makes it straightforward to write types that act like bit sets. `enum { input = 1, output = 2 };` can be used to represent something that does both input and output by assigning `input | output` (i.e., 3) to the value. That can be made easier to use by overloading the various bitwise operators that you need, so that they return a value of the enumerated type.

Comment: @BillKotsias Yes, it's not a C-style cast, you are aboslutely correct.

Comment: @PeteBecker it perfectly makes sense for flags, i see

Comment: @NathanOliver They're all valid enum values ;) #usualargumentsaboutwhatenumsreallymean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imho, direct initialization is like:

```
enum Value {
  kValue = 5,
};

Value e = kValue;
```

And there is disadvantage of `static_cast` and your initialization vs direct initialization. Initialization by 'kValue' protects you from nonexistent value, improves readability, etc.

I think, both cases are equal. But second case is more readable.

Comment: I am sorry, I have clarified my question with an edit

Comment: I think, both cases are equal. But second case is more readable.

Comment: If no-one else disagrees, you could perhaps paste your comment into your answer above, so that I accept it :grin: