# How to access to the components of class in header file and print their addresses?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

I starts to learn the Multiple Inheritance in C++ and I want to print out the addresses of the class components from the header file.

The original header file defines several classes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
class Account
{
  public:
  Account() {}
  unsigned long A1;
};

class Employee : public Account
{
 public:
 Employee() {}
 unsigned long E1;
};
class Student : public Account
{
 public:
 Student() {}
 unsigned long S1;
};
class Work_Study : public Employee, public Student
{
  public:
  Work_Study() {}
  unsigned long W1;
};
```

The cpp file is below:

```
Work_Study Obj_WS; // declare a Work_Study object;
Work_Study * Obj_WS_ptr = &Obj_WS; 
int main() {

    std::cout << "Employee Account" << &((Account *) Obj_WS_ptr->A1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Employee" << &((Employee *) Obj_WS_ptr->E1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Student Account" << &((Account *) Obj_WS_ptr->A1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Student" << &((Student *) Obj_WS_ptr->S1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Work_Study" << &(Obj_WS_ptr->W1) << std::endl;
    return 0;
 }
```

There are currently two errors:

The first one is about the ambiguous request for these components.

```
Test_MI.cpp:12:51: error: request for member ‘A1’ is ambiguous
```

And with the following note:

```
note: candidates are: long unsigned int Account::A1 unsigned long A1;
```

Should I declare the class again in cpp file? Or is there other way?

The other is: lvalue required as unary '&' operand. What does this error means as the components are long unsigned int?

In this multiple inheritance, there are two Accounts for Employee and Student, so if we want to access the Account for Student, we need to cast the pointer to access it because the memory layout is left hand side first with accessing Employee object firstly.

Comment: Please show the definition of `Work_Study`.  And read about how to create a [mre].

Comment: The definition is like this:                                                                                       
 class Work_Study : public Employee, public Student
{
public:
  Work_Study() {}
  unsigned long W1;
};

Comment: Please add that to your question, and please add all the other missing class definitions.  In other words, make a [mre].  But ... what's with all the casts?  I think you need to do some [background reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: I would add the codes from header file. Also, because I think too much codes sometimes would mess people up, so I just post the main source code. I would explain the casts in the post.

Answer (score 0):

`(Account *) Obj_WS_ptr->A1` is ambiguous because `Work_Study` has 2 `Account` instances, and thus 2 `A1` members - one inherited from `Employee` and one inherited from `Student`.  To let the compiler know which `Account` and thus which `A1` you want to access, you would have to either:

- change your type-cast to use `Employee*` or `Student*` instead of `Account*` (and use `static_cast` so the casts are easier for you to read and safer for the compiler to parse):

```cpp
std::cout << "Employee Account" << &(static_cast<Employee*>(Obj_WS_ptr)->A1) << std::endl;
std::cout << "Student Account" << &(static_cast<Student*>(Obj_WS_ptr)->A1) << std::endl;
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/sRDUir)

- qualify which variable to access without using any type-cast at all:

```cpp
std::cout << "Employee Account" << &(Obj_WS_ptr->Employee::A1) << std::endl;
std::cout << "Student Account" << &(Obj_WS_ptr->Student::A1) << std::endl;
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/pJqakP)

The alternative is to use [*virtual inheritance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance) instead:

```cpp
class Account
{
public:
  Account() {}
  unsigned long A1;
};

class Employee : public virtual Account
{
public:
  Employee() {}
  unsigned long E1;
};

class Student : public virtual Account
{
public:
  Student() {}
  unsigned long S1;
};

class Work_Study : public Employee, public Student
{
public:
  Work_Study() {}
  unsigned long W1;
};
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/A1G368)

This way, only 1 `Account` will exist in `Work_Study` even though `Employee` and `Student` both derive from `Account`, thus solving the so-called ["diamond problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem) that your classes are creating.

Comment: Alright, I get the addresses for the components, thanks a lot. By the way, do you know how to return the address of the casted object pointer? I think these pointers have no address form, so how to use '&' to access?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Please clarify, preferably with an example you are trying to solve.

Comment: OK, I am trying to return the address value of object pointer under the influence of casting, like: std::cout << "Address of Object Pointer under casting of Employee A1" << &((Employee *)Obj_WS_ptr) << std::endl;

Comment: You don't need to use `&` in that case. The value of the casted pointer as-is is the address you are looking for, eg: `std::cout << "Address of Object Pointer under casting of Employee " << static_cast<Employee*>(Obj_WS_ptr) << std::endl;` You really should start getting in the habit of using C++-style casts instead of C-style casts. [What is the difference between static_cast<> and C style casting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609163/)

Comment: The results would be the addresses of the components in class Student and Employee, but I am trying to find the address of the pointer itself. The Pointers have values which are the components' addresses, but what are the Pointers' address? not the content, but the location of pointers.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would ever want to take the address of a casted pointer, that is not useful in any way. Besides, you can't take the address of any temporary value to begin with, you would have to save it to a variable first, but then you would be getting the address of that variable.

Comment: how about store it in a pointer and return that pointer's value which is the address of the casted pointer? But how to declare this pointer as the casted pointer has casted type

Comment: Again, you can't take the *address* of the result of a type-cast, so you couldn't put the *address* of the casted pointer into another pointer to begin with.  All you can store is the *value* of the casted pointer, which is exactly what `cout << (Employee*)Obj_WS_ptr` and `cout << static_cast<Employee*>(Obj_WS_ptr)` print out (since the casted pointer is assigned to a `void*` parameter of `operator<<`). I don't think you are understanding how pointers and type-casts actually work.

Comment: The previous line cout << &(static_cast<Employee*>(Obj_WS_ptr), which has '&',  returns the same value of the line which has same content except '&', should this be? So why '&' has the same effect in this case?

Comment: I have no idea what you are referring to, you are not making any sense. But `&static_cast<Employee*>(Obj_WS_ptr)` is not legal. And the `(` after the `&`, but a missing closing `)` after `Obj_WS_ptr)`, implies you actually copied that from a line that refers to a *member* of the casted `Employee` but you didn't show that completely, such as `&(static_cast<Employee*>(Obj_WS_ptr)->E1)`