# How to interpret the explicit cast operator

Tags: c++, unary-operator, typecast-operator

As we can invoke the explicit cast operator, using static_cast, a C-style cast, or a constructor style cast. I am confusing how exactly the operator interpret to these three casts.

For example, consider the following code. The `const Money& balance` in `display_balance()` can be cast to double in three ways. So what are these cast interpret. What I thought is there is only one explicit cast operator in Money, so the calling may would be `balance.operator ()`. I really can't figure out how does the three different casting be interpreted.

```cpp
class Money
{
public:
    Money() : amount{ 0.0 } {};
    Money(double _amount) : amount{ _amount } {};
    explicit operator double() const { return amount; }
private:
    double amount;
};

void display_balance(const Money& balance)
{
    std::cout << "The balance is: " << (double)balance << "\n";
    std::cout << "The balance is: " << double(balance) << "\n";
    std::cout << "The balance is: " << static_cast<double>(balance) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: All three casts do the same thing.  They tell the compiler "Hey, give me `blanace` as a `double`." and compiler goes "Okay, let me check.  Oh hey, there is an `operator double()` so I call that for you and give you that `double` you wanted.".

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. All three versions call the `operator double()`, just using different forms.

Comment: cppinsights.io might help [Demo](https://cppinsights.io/s/0c65c098).

Comment: @NathanOliver @ChrisMM So complier did the map of different forms to` operator double()`, other than the operator double() done these interpret work?

Comment: `(T)x` and `x(T)` are the same thing. They are explicit conversions, which will try to find the series of cast operations that will allow `x` to convert to `T`. In this case, it is exactly `static_cast<double>(balance)` so functionally all three conversions are exactly the same, though `static_cast` is considered safer. The `operator double()` simply makes these conversions possible, all three expressions just call `operator double()`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks, this is really a great website.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks, according to the demo give by Jarod42. Personally, I think (T)x and x(T) are different, (T)x and static_cast<T>(x) are same. (T)x is a c-style casting, x(T) called the x's constructor with T's casting object.

Comment: @amont You mean T(x)?

Comment: See here for the order the compiler tries to do a casts when using an explicit c-style cast - _"...the compiler attempts to interpret it as the following cast expressions, in this order:..."_ - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast

Comment: @Sebastian For, example there are two class `Employer and Employee`， and there is an employer object `mike`.  `(Employee)mike` is a c-style casting which would be mike.operator(). While, I think `Employee(mike)` first called the casting, then the Employee construct an object with the casting result, which would be `Employee(mike.operator())`. Thank you.

Comment: @amont `(T)x` and `T(x)` are 100% identical for all types `T`. It is unfortunate that this is the case, because it is understandable that the syntax makes it look like `T(x)` would be the one-argument equivalent of `T(x, y)`. But that is not how the C++ language defines it. The one-argument case is special and defined to be equal to the C-style explicit cast. Note however that even if `T(x)` was direct-initialization from the argument via constructor call, the result may be a call to an `operator T` of `x` via `T`'s copy/move constructor.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yes, all of them call `operator double()`.  However, `double(balance)` is interprets as `double(balance.operator double())`.  I think `balance.operator double()` return a temporary double value `tmp`, then double inited like `double(tmp)`.

Comment: @amont `double(balance)` and `(double)balance` are identical by definition. You can see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Y9fxscjh5) that they produce identical assembly, with or without optimizations. `double(x)` is the same thing as `x` if `x` is already a `double`. The conversion tries to find a series of casts that allow `x` to be a `T`, in this case it will determine that the conversion requires a series of no cast at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Type Casting

It isn't the syntax you use when casting that determines **how** that cast is performed, it's the context based on the variable types.

When the compiler sees that you're trying to cast from `Money` to `double`, it tries to figure out a way to accomplish that - in every case, it uses the `Money::operator double()` operator because in every case `double` was specified as the target type.

**C++** almost always allows you to accomplish one task in multiple different ways due to historical reasons; even its name alludes to its original goal: [extending the **C** language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B).

Consider the following syntaxes:

```cpp
Money balance(100.0);

// C-Style Cast
(double)balance;              //< double with value 100.0

// Functional Cast
double(balance);              //< double with value 100.0
double{ balance };            //< double with value 100.0

// Static Cast
static_cast<double>(balance); //< double with value 100.0
```

Once this is compiled, there isn't really any difference in which syntax you used; all of them call `Money::operator double()`.

Of course, casting is always subject to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

**Note: While in this case all of the approaches are the same, this is not true in all cases.**
Whenever possible, use `static_cast` instead of c-style or functional casts - you can read more about why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609163/what-is-the-difference-between-static-cast-and-c-style-casting).

## Explicit vs. Implicit Type Casting

Consider the following objects:

- `Money` is your class.
- `Cash` is a copy of `Money` that allows implicit casting.

```cpp
class Money
{
public:
    Money() : amount{ 0.0 } {};
    Money(double _amount) : amount{ _amount } {};

    // This is an explicit casting operator:
    explicit operator double() const { return amount; }
private:
    double amount;
};

class Cash
{
public:
    Cash() : amount{ 0.0 } {};
    Cash(double _amount) : amount{ _amount } {};

    // This is an implicit casting operator
    operator double() const { return amount; }
private:
    double amount;
};
```

Now consider the following function that accepts a `double`:

```cpp
void BuySomething(double amount) {}
```

In order to `BuySomething()` with `Money`, we must explicitly cast it to `double` first:

```cpp
Money money(500.0);

BuySomething(static_cast<double>(money));
BuySomething((double)money);
BuySomething(double(money));
BuySomething(double{ money });

// We can also just call the operator directly:
BuySomething(money.operator double());
```

However, we can `BuySomething()` with `Cash` without explicitly casting it first:

```cpp
Cash cash(500.0);

BuySomething(cash);

// You can still use explicit casting:
BuySomething(static_cast<double>(cash));
BuySomething((double)cash);
BuySomething(double(cash));
BuySomething(double{ cash });

BuySomething(cash.operator double())
```

This is because when the compiler sees `BuySomething(cash);`, it knows that `BuySomething()` **doesn't accept `Cash`** - it accepts `double` - so rather than just throwing an error, it tries to figure out a way to convert `Cash` to `double`, and in the process finds our conversion operator.

*If you notice something wrong with my explaination, let me know in the comments.*